# Knockout.js - change event at display none input

Tags: knockout.js

I have an input

```
<input type="text" name="Name" id="Name" data-bind="value: Name" style="display: none;" >
```

and a View Model:

```
name  : ko.observable()
```

The name value is added to the input when I click a link in another control.

But the 'change' event is not firing.

How can I get the value of the input to change?

Comment: `data-bind="value: Name"` shouldn't `Name` be `name`? on the HTML

Comment: What is "link click"? Show the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps, you can replace the *change* event by subscribing to changes of the observable (with the same effect).

```
<input type="text" name="Name" id="Name" data-bind="value: name" style="display: none;">

var Model = function() {
  var self = this;
  this.name = ko.observable();  
  this.name.subscribe(function () {
        alert(self.name());                
  });
};
ko.applyBindings(new Model());
```

Comment: Thanks. But I decide to use custom ko.bindingHandlers

    ko.bindingHandlers.updateAction = {
        update: function (el) {
            ... my actions here ...
        }
    }

    <input type="text" style="display: none" data-bind="value: Name, updateAction : {}" />

Comment: change event is not automatically triggered when changing value of input programmatically (see also [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5760873/trigger-change-event-when-setting-selects-value-with-val-function)). After changing the value, you need to explicitly trigger the change event. In jquery: $('input').val("aa").change(). And only then, you will be able to handle the change in your custom binding.