# Javascript: Trigger 'change' eventlistener when updating <select> value

Tags: javascript, event-listener

*Note: **Not using jQuery**, before you mark this as a duplicate make sure other Q/A is pure JS.*

I set my event listener like this, which works perfectly when triggered via html:

```
document.getElementById('activitySelector').addEventListener('change', function() {
  console.log("I work triggered by html but not js")
}
```

I'm adding additional functionality where I change the select value via javascript, which works in that the html updates, but the eventListener is never triggered:

```
document.getElementById("activitySelector").value = interactiveType
```

Comment: That's right, programmatically changing value of select is not supposed and will not trigger onchange event.

Comment: @dfsq can it be triggered manually?

Comment: @dfsq Maybe I will just wrap my code as a function and just call that in both places. Manually triggering would probably end up being more code. Should I delete my question you think?

Comment: Dispatching event is not that verbose (unless you support old IE). I guess something like this `const event = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents"); event.initEvent("change", true, true); document.getElementById("activitySelector").dispatchEvent(event)`. Took from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490825/how-to-trigger-event-in-javascript

Comment: @dfsq I was going to delete this question at first but I think sometimes simple information like what you are posting can be very useful when coming from search. Would you post your comment in answer form? Or do you think I should delete?

Comment: I don't see any problem with this question worth deleting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my initial solution. Just have the event handler trigger your code wrapped as a function. That way you can just call that same function when updating via javascript.

As @dfsq has pointed out this is just how it works. Manually triggering the event would probably take more code than this method:

```
// All code originally in eventListener now in function
function onActivityChange() {
  console.log("I work triggered by html and js")
}

// Call above function from eventlistener
document.getElementById('activitySelector').addEventListener('change', onActivityChange)

// Trigger same function after updating value
document.getElementById("activitySelector").value = interactiveType
onActivityChange()
```

Comment: `addEventListener('change', onActivityChange)` is shorter if you want to do it that way

Comment: @pwolaq you could also argue that your suggested method is more maintainable if more than 1 developer is working on the same project. Post it as an answer?

Comment: I'm sorry to have to point out the obvious, but this answer is an answer to the question "how do I call a function from two other functions?", which is so basic it should've never ended up here. Not seeing how simple the problem actually is doesn't warrant keeping this question, imo.

Comment: @ChrisG this is the pure JS version of another question, which seems to be extremely popular, what makes my question so different from this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5760873/trigger-change-event-when-setting-selects-value-with-val-function

Comment: A solution that changed the behavior so onchange is triggered automatically would be much more impressive; again, the workaround is obvious and trivial. The other question is asking how to best *implement* the workaround the OP found *himself*, not what the workaround is. That's the crucial difference.

Comment: @ChrisG feel free to post a better answer.

Comment: @ChrisG if you read my other comments I've asked pwolaq and dfsq both to post their suggested solutions. Doesn't mean I'm not going to accept or upvote a better solution.

Comment: This isn't about the solutions. The *question* is the problem. I don't mean to be arrogant or rude, therefore I'm going to just repeat myself: **The solution is obvious and trivial.**

Comment: @ChrisG fine flag it

Answer (score 3):

To achieve what you want you should create the event manually and *dispatch* it. It's not difficult, as you could see here: http://www.2ality.com/2013/06/triggering-events.html?m=1