# How to programmatically click Select element and trigger onChange handler?

Tags: javascript, html

For example, with the following code. I tried several solutions.

```
function handleChange() {
    alert('hello')
}

<select id="names" onchange="handleChange()">
    <option>Foo</option>
    <option>Bar</option>
</select>
```

**Solution 1.**

```
document.getElementById('#select').selectedIndex = 1
```

This would change the value and display of select but doesn't trigger handleChange();

**Solution 2**

```
var element = document.getElementById('names');
var event = new Event('change');
element.dispatchEvent(event);
```

This returns true but still doesn't trigger handleChange();

---

Any ideas on how to do this? Or can it actually be done? Solution has to be javascript/html only and sadly no jQuery.

Comment: why dont u just call handleChange yourself? O___o

Comment: @Rico I'm actually clicking the select via test so I can't call handleChange.

Comment: can you use jquery?

Comment: @Mosd nope no jquery, solution will be called via test using mocha.

Comment: @KaelVergara thanks, posted answer

Answer (score 13, accepted):

try this, it worked for me...your problem can just be you didnt change the actual value on solution 2 before triggering change :

```js
    function handleChange() {
        alert('hello')
    }


 console.log(document.getElementById('names'));
 document.getElementById('names').selectedIndex = 1;
 document.getElementById('names').dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
```

```html
    <select id="names" onchange="handleChange()">
        <option>Foo</option>
        <option>Bar</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: This actually works:  https://plnkr.co/edit/SCrZMftWYez80fgmXZ4M?p=preview

thanks! Will mark as accepted answer!

Comment: Also, make sure the event bubbles: new Event('change', {bubbles: true})

Answer (score 1):

Strange @KaelVergara, I copied your code and it is working for me

```
<script>
function handleChange123() {
    alert('hello')
}
</script>

<select id="names123" onchange="handleChange123()">
    <option>Foo</option>
    <option>Bar</option>
</select>

<script>
var element = document.getElementById('names123');
var event = new Event('change');
element.dispatchEvent(event);
</script>
```

Comment: Also, make sure the event bubbles: new Event('change', {bubbles: true})

Answer (score 1):

TRY THIS:

```js
function handleChange() {
  alert('hello')
}
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById('names').selectedIndex = 1;
  handleChange();
}
```

```html
<select id="names" onchange="handleChange()">
  <option>Foo</option>
  <option>Bar</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

one way would be as below from the below answer for another question here
[Trigger change() event when setting <select>'s value with val() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5760873/trigger-change-event-when-setting-selects-value-with-val-function)

```
 $('#selectField').val(10).change();
```

or simple one just to trigger the event

```
 $('#selectField').change();
```

or if you do not want to use Jquery
you can use the below method

```
 const $roomID = document.querySelector('.roomID')
$roomID.onchange = function () {
   if ($("#ddlRoom").val() !== "") {
       var ID = $("#ddlRoom").val();
       console.log(ID);
} ;
};

$roomID.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
```

Comment: your answer is for jquery, op is using javascript