# Change dropdown option value via JS not working

Tags: javascript

I am trying to change the dropdown option value at the end from "10 rows" to "50 rows". The code below changes value to "50 rows" but it does not trigger the corresponding data. It's being run manually but not via JS. URL is https://trendlyne.com/mutual-fund/nav/6309/icici-prudential-technology-fund-direct-plan-growth/

```
document.querySelector('.select-wrap select').getElementsByTagName('option')[4].selected = 'selected';
```

OR

```
document.querySelector(".select-wrap select").value='50'
```

Comment: Check this answer, it may be what you want: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42944308/how-to-programmatically-click-select-element-and-trigger-onchange-handler

Comment: Thanks. None of the answer in the link works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

trigger change event manually after selecting the value

```
document.querySelector('.select-wrap select').getElementsByTagName('option')[4].selected = true;
document.querySelector('.select-wrap select').dispatchEvent(new Event('change', {bubbles: true}));
```