# Why does on change not trigger in this example?

Tags: jquery, select

The call to start() should trigger the change

http://jsfiddle.net/txqed/2/

```
$(function () {
    $('#ddlTo').on("change", function () {
        $("#div1").html($(this).val());
    })

    start();
});

function start() {
    $('#ddlTo').val("master");
}
```

Comment: I don't see a problem? It's working as it should.

Comment: what is the behavior you are looking for?

Comment: Another proof that any question can get a +1...

Comment: Another proof that some SO people are very harsh on newcomers with poor English.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The change event only fires when the user initiates the change](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4672505/why-does-the-jquery-change-event-not-trigger-when-i-set-the-value-of-a-select-us)

Answer (score 2):

Your question isn't entirely clear, but my guess is you'd like to fire the change event when you initialise the value of the select.

This should do what you expect:

```
$('#ddlTo').val("master").change();
```

[The change event only fires when the user initiates the change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4672505/why-does-the-jquery-change-event-not-trigger-when-i-set-the-value-of-a-select-us).

Comment: Assuming you and I both understood the question, then your answer now definitely answers it :)

Answer (score -1):

As alnorth29 pointed out, your question is not clear but maybe this is what you want:

http://jsfiddle.net/txqed/3/

```
$('#ddlTo').on("change", function() {
    $("#div1").html($(this).val());
    start();
});
```

Basically changing the select box back to "master" after displaying user selected value.

**Edit:** I misunderstood your question. As pointed out in the comments this behavior is not very logical.

Comment: That would not be logical in any way I can imagine