# Radio button change event on checked element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have a table which contains two columns.

Let say First column contains Parent Name, and second child names.
First parent element is selected by default. I am hiding children of every parent except first element.

Here is the code which works like Accordion(At a time only one should be visible) :

```
$(document).ready(function()  {
    var childs = $('.tableCellWBorderGray > div'); // child divs
    childs.hide();

    $("input:radio[name=attribute]").change(function(){
              var parent = $(this).parent().next(); // In our case, second td
              var kids = parent.children();
              childs.slideUp('slow');
              kids.slideDown('slow');
        });
     // select first element and trigger change event to show childs.  
    $('input:radio[name=attribute]:nth(0)').attr('checked',true).trigger('change');
});
```

This works fine on every other browser.

But in IE with `Document Mode: IE7 Standards` When I click on first checked elements, the `change` gets fired. Though this happens only once If I click on checked element. I want to prevent it.

I have looked into  [Why does the jquery change event not trigger when I set the value of a select using val()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4672505/why-does-the-jquery-change-event-not-trigger-when-i-set-the-value-of-a-select-us)

The accepted answer says that

> The change event requires an actual browser event initiated by the
>   user instead of via javascript code.

Is there any work around ?

Full Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/CZZeR/2/

Comment: For me the code works fine on IE9.

Comment: @KishorSubedi: It doesn't work if you set `Document Mode: IE7 Standards`. I need that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to override the **attr** function to fire **change** event

Code:

```
$(function() {
    var $attrFn = $.fn.attr;
    $.fn.extend({
        attr: function() {
            var attrCatch = $attrFn.apply(this, arguments);
            if (arguments.length) {
                $(this).change();
            }
            return attrCatch;
        }
    });
});
```

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CZZeR/3/)

Comment: `change` event gets fired without overriding also. The problem is that I think it does not recognize it when I again click on the same element

Comment: It doesn't work if you set Document Mode: IE7 Standards. I need that due to legacy reasons.