# Jquery keyup doesn't detect content changes by javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code which puts the content of my input fields into a preview div area:

JS

```
function fieldPreview() {
$('.input').on('keyup', function() {
    $('#' + $(this).data('id')).html(this.value);
});
}
```

HTML

```
<input class="input" type="text" name="title" placeholder="Job Title" data-id="title">
<div id="title"></div>
```

My issue comes from the fact that two of my input fields are a little more complicated. One field uses google map autosuggest. When I click on the autosuggestion link it updates the text field but doesn't update the preview in the div until I actually modify the input manually by adding or removing another letter.

Is there a better way in jquery to monitor changes in an input field? This will allow me to put the contents of the field into the div even if it has been put there by javascript rather than a keyup.

**Here is an example of jquery clearing the contents of the input field but it not being reflected in the DIV: http://jsfiddle.net/xDA9p/5/**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detect all changes to a <input type="text"> (immediately) using JQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1948332/detect-all-changes-to-a-input-type-text-immediately-using-jquery) -- make sure to read the comments about detecting changes through JS.

Comment: Basically there is no event that is triggered when the value is changed via JavaScript. After the value you changed, you have to trigger the event handler "manually".

Comment: See also [Why does the jquery change event not trigger when I set the value of a select using val()?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4672505/218196).

Comment: @FelixKling could you explain to me how to trigger it manually?

Comment: I don't know how the autosuggestion works, but maybe there is some kind of "completion" or "select" event which gets fired when the value was changed. You'd have to listen to those events and then call `$('.input').trigger('keyup')` (for example) to trigger the event handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `change paste keyup input` events.

```
$('.input').on('change paste keyup input', function() {
  $('#' + $(this).data('id')).html(this.value);
});
```

Comment: I'm afraid this still doesn't work in chrome for a google autosuggest change in input