# create a condition for <input> to have value before an event happens jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i created a condition that when a button is clicked, it will get the value of my **ID** from `<input id="id" class="req">` box, and will display the associated name of that ID and put it in **Name**`<input id="name" class="req">` box.

so when i type `1`, i will get `BOB`. pretty basic.

i also have a condition, that both `<input>` box should have values, before a specific `<div>` will appear. so by default this `<div>` is *hidden*.

the part im struggling is, whenever i click the button, then i get the name, even though, i have successfully filled my 2 `<input>` boxes, the `<div>` still wont appear.

this is my code.

```
//<input> conditions

$('input.req').on("keyup keypress change", function () {
  $('input.req').each(function() { 
    if($(this).val() != "") {
        $("#content").show();
    }
    else {
        $("#content").hide();
    }
  });
});
```

again, if you type 1, you will get bob. but the `<div>` wont show up. but if you **manually**, fill in the textboxes, the `<div>` will appear.

what i want to happen is, input my *ID*, click the button, get the *name*, place the *name* inside inside my *name* `<input>` box and make the `<div>` appear.

Comment: y are you using `$.each`? are there many input.req. PLease post html also.

Comment: Changing the value of an input with jQuery doesn't always fire the change event. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4672505/why-does-the-jquery-change-event-not-trigger-when-i-set-the-value-of-a-select-us

Comment: @bhb i have 3 <input> but opted for 2 only for simplicity. i used each, almost all of the things ive read, they usually refer to `each` to check **each** element. not sure if im following it right though..

Comment: @lemieuxster thanks for this link! this solved my issue. i simply added `.change();` and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You should also check your input boxes in Ajax success handler because as for now you only been doing it on key events:

```
$.ajax({
   url: //url,
   success: function() {
      $('input.req').each(function() { 
         if($(this).val() != "") {
            $("#content").show();
         }
         else {
            $("#content").hide();
         }
      });
   }    
})
```

Answer (score 0):

your problem is you go throw every input every time an imput is change.
just remove `$('input.req').each(function() {` and all will be ok.

Comment: why put -1? it's that. when your input change you have just to call the code that show/hide content. For the moment your code will pass throw every input.req and as the last input.req is empty the content is hidden.