# Trigger change event on textarea in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I try to trigger the event while changing the value in textarea. I bind the `change input paste keyup` and its works fine when I type the content manually or paste. But I dont know how to trigger when changes occur using jquery. `$("#inptxt").val("Jquery");`

HTML

```
<textarea id="inptxt" ></textarea>
<div id="res" ></div>
<input type="button" value="click" id="but" />
```

jQuery

```
$("#inptxt").on("change input paste keyup", function() {
   $("#res").html(jQuery(this).val());
});
$("#but").bind("click",function(){
    $("#inptxt").val("Jquery");
});
```

Example [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dineshkani/ZVcG4/1/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set a value per script does not trigger a change event.
If you need the event you must manually trigger it.

```
$("#but").bind("click",function(){
    $("#inptxt").val("Jquery").trigger('change');
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZVcG4/2/)

Answer (score 4):

Browser doesn't recognize the text updation within the input field `#inptxt`, as it is done programmatically using jquery. so you have to manually trigger change event after updating the text value.

**Jquery Code:**

```
$("#inptxt").on("change input paste keyup", function() {
    $("#res").html(jQuery(this).val());
});
$("#but").bind("click",function(){
    $("#inptxt").val("Jquery").change();
});
```

**Live Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/ZVcG4/6/

**Reference SO Question :[Why does the jquery change event not trigger when I set the value of a select using val()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4672505/why-does-the-jquery-change-event-not-trigger-when-i-set-the-value-of-a-select-us)**

Happy Coding:)

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that `textarea` is its own input type, as it were, so you would need to make your first line simply include that, and you will have live updates as you type...

```
$("#inptxt").on("change input paste keyup textarea", function() {
   $("#res").html(jQuery(this).val());
});
$("#but").bind("click",function(){
    $("#inptxt").val("Jquery not trigger the change function");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7wnrxh6c/