# How to know input indirect change?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I use jQuery to know my input changes .

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#id_back_ground_color").change(function(){
    alert("hello");
  });
    $("#salam").click(function(){
     alert("hey");
     $("#id_back_ground_color").val('changed!');
  }); 
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input id="id_back_ground_color" type="text">
<button id="salam" >

</body>
</html>
```

When I click on the button I get a "hey" alert but I don't get the "hello" alert. Why?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does the jquery change event not trigger when I set the value of a select using val()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4672505/why-does-the-jquery-change-event-not-trigger-when-i-set-the-value-of-a-select-us)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no link between a click on the button and an edit in the `id_back_ground_color` field.

> The change event is sent to an element when its value changes. This
>   event is limited to  elements,  boxes and 
>   elements. For select boxes, checkboxes, and radio buttons, the event
>   is fired immediately when the user makes a selection with the mouse,
>   but for the other element types the event is deferred until the
>   element loses focus.

From http://api.jquery.com/change/

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
 $("#id_back_ground_color").val('changed!');
```

to this

```
 $("#id_back_ground_color").val('changed!').trigger( "change" );
```