# Update input value when using jQuery UI slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, onchange

I'm using the jQuery slider to change the value of an input.

```
div#slider
input#amount
```

I use the value of the input to perform some math with:

```
$("input#amount").change(function() {
...
```

The thing is, when I enter some value in the input, it works fine, but playing with the slider, the value appears to change, but no calculation is performed.

jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/mfeqoL7L/

Why/How to fix this?

Thx!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does the jquery change event not trigger when I set the value of a select using val()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4672505/why-does-the-jquery-change-event-not-trigger-when-i-set-the-value-of-a-select-us)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that setting a value on an input element using `.val` doesn't fire the `change` event: [Why does the jquery change event not trigger when I set the value of a select using val()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4672505/why-does-the-jquery-change-event-not-trigger-when-i-set-the-value-of-a-select-us)

To manually fire the event call `.change` explicitly after setting the `.val`.