# Woocommerce plus/minus quantity button changing value but not working actually

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I have created a plus/minus quantity button for woocommerce single product page.created a new quantity-input.php

```
<?php
    if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) 
        exit; // Exit if accessed directly
?>
<div class="quantity">
    <input class="minus" type="button" value="-">
    <input type="number" step="<?php echo esc_attr( $step ); ?>" <?php if ( is_numeric( $min_value ) ) : ?>min="<?php echo esc_attr( $min_value ); ?>"<?php endif; ?> <?php if ( is_numeric( $max_value ) ) : ?>max="<?php echo esc_attr( $max_value ); ?>"<?php endif; ?> name="<?php echo esc_attr( $input_name ); ?>" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $input_value ); ?>" title="<?php _ex( 'Qty', 'Product quantity input tooltip', 'woocommerce' ) ?>" class="input-text qty text" size="4" />
    <input class="plus" type="button" value="+">
</div>
```

```js
$('.plus').on('click', function(e) {
    var val = parseInt($(this).prev('input').val());
    $(this).prev('input').attr( 'value', val+1 );
});

$('.minus').on('click', function(e) {
    var val = parseInt($(this).next('input').val());
    if (val !== 0) {
        $(this).next('input').val( val-1 );
    } 
});
```

The above code changes the value of the text visually box but doesn't change the value in the code.As a result, woocommerce doesn't get any changes of quantity.On the other hand if I press up/down button of keyboard, changes of value is being got by woocommerce.I think it is happening because I have used `.val()` instead of `.attr()`, I changed to `attr()` many times but in vain.

Comment: This seems to work fine in jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/o2amr91n/

Comment: Yes .attr() is working but still woocommerce doesn't get value of input.Example is here http://jollyfine.co/shop/product/12-box-of-pick-your-own/

Comment: You can try looking into this plugin: https://nwordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-quantity-increment/

Comment: It looks like input tags with these classes `input-text qty text` register the change when u click on the quantity number. And those changes reflect on your basket as well. Maybe on clicking `.plus` and `.minus` u should update the closest input element with these classes: `input-text qty text` as well.

Comment: @sandeep You are right.The problem is in there.I checked it by removing  `input-text qty text` .Then woocommerce doesn't get input value anymore.Can you suggest me how to fix it with my js?

Comment: First of all, high five for purchasing my Mix and Match plugin! The issue seems to be that Mix and Match uses some complex front-end validation stuff using jQuery before the form is submitted. What appears to be happening is that changing an input's value via jQuery does not trigger the `.change()` event that is monitoring the form and re-validating every time a quantity is modified. This is weird, but appears to be a problem with jQuery itself. See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/57deh38c/1/).

Comment: That said, this is a common enough feature that I will look into how to make it work.... assuming that it won't take forever. Already seeing [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4672519/383847) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3179392/383847) to help work around this.

Answer (score 6):

Following up on my above comment, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4672519/383847) explains that jQuery's `change` event is only triggered by a manual browser event. Therefore, changing the value of an input via jQuery does *not* trigger the `change` event so we need to trigger it manually by calling `.change()` on the input.

Here is my updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/helgatheviking/9ekhjk1d/13/) showing the fix outside of the Mix and Match context.

Pertaining to Mix and Match specifically, we just need to chain a `.change()` event to the input after the value has been changed. I tweaked how the input is identified, but that's not a big difference.

**Edit:** Now takes into account the input's "step".

```
$('.quantity').on('click', '.plus', function(e) {
    $input = $(this).prev('input.qty');
    var val = parseInt($input.val());
    var step = $input.attr('step');
    step = 'undefined' !== typeof(step) ? parseInt(step) : 1;
    $input.val( val + step ).change();
});

$('.quantity').on('click', '.minus', 
    function(e) {
    $input = $(this).next('input.qty');
    var val = parseInt($input.val());
    var step = $input.attr('step');
    step = 'undefined' !== typeof(step) ? parseInt(step) : 1;
    if (val > 0) {
        $input.val( val - step ).change();
    } 
});
```

I'll be adding this to my FAQ soon.

Comment: Hi! I have a problem in the Checkout page: the quantity variation does not update the price, and as if she did not recognize the new input value number. do you  know how fix?

Comment: I have move the jQuery in the php files, now work but only one time, after the first update is not passible make any variation. Cloud help me pleace? :)

Comment: @MarcoRomano You should make a new question and perhaps someone can help you.

Comment: Thank you! anyway in this time I have fix the problem! :) I use a part of js form one plug-in, now work... (i know is not the best solution but work and is light!) Best

Answer (score 3):

@helgatheviking your code doesn't work for me.But I am happy that your suggestions solved my problem.I just added `.change()` along with `.val()` and it works :)

the final code Is:

```
$('.plus').on('click',function(e){

var val = parseInt($(this).prev('input').val());

$(this).prev('input').val( val+1 ).change();


});
$('.minus').on('click',function(e){

var val = parseInt($(this).next('input').val());
if(val !== 0){
    $(this).next('input').val( val-1 ).change();
} });
```

Comment: Since our code looks mostly the same, I'd guess your HTML markup is a little different and my CSS selectors don't work for you.