# Listen in Content Script for when AJAX response changes textarea val

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome-extension, content-script, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm writing a `WebExtension` for a text editor. When the user clicks a button, `format` the editor fires an ajax request and then returns the formatted text. I need my addon to listen for a change in the `textarea`.

I've tried using `onchange` or `oninput`, but when the response is received, these events *aren't* triggered. The ajax response sets the body with this function (not my own):

```
function setBody(text) {
  $(opts.codeEl).val(text); // opts.codeEl is the textarea in question
}
```

the `ajax` response looks like this:

> `{"Body":"Hello World","Error":""}`

Is it possible to handle this ajax request/response from a **WebExtension** **Content Script**? Somehow listen for a change in `val` of the `textarea` in the *DOM*? Can I listen and *intercept* the response?

The ajax request is being sent and received in the website's javascript code, **isolated** from the content script which I'm using (the WebExtension code) for the editor. the request is this

```
function fmt() {
  loading();
  var data = {"body": body()};
  if ($(opts.fmtImportEl).is(":checked")) {
    data["imports"] = "true";
  }
  $.ajax("/fmt", {
    data: data,
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
      if (data.Error) {
        setError(data.Error);
      } else {
        setBody(data.Body);
        setError("");
      }
    }
  });
}
```

### Edit

Injecting a `ajaxComplete` handler:

```
  $(document).ajaxComplete(function(event, jqxhr, options) {
    if(options.url === "/fmt") {
      console.log("fmtted");
      $('#code').change();
    }
  });
```

Into the target site header will be called when the `ajax` response is received. However, when trying to modify the `DOM` using injected scripts (by, for example, calling `change()` or `onchange()`, for security reasons, it raises an `Error: Permission denied to access property "apply"` error.

Comment: Are you trying to check response of server to `$.ajax()` call or `change` event of `textarea`?

Comment: 1. Does this text editor provide its own js API and event subscription? 2. You may have to [spoof `val` method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40908082) using a [DOM-injected script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9517879)

Comment: @guest271314 check the `change` event

Comment: @wOxxOm yes... I think. I'm going to look into those links now

Comment: @Nevermore `options.url` would not be equal to `"/fmt"`, but rather, the full URL.

Comment: @guest271314 when I log simply `options.url`, or `options` the result is `"/fmt"`

Comment: @Nevermore Ok. Still not sure what issue is?

Comment: @guest271314 I think I get it - I'm trying to call either `change()` or `onchange()` using injected js, and so I'm denied because of my permissions (to protect against cross site scripting). Either I have to send a message to my content script another way (than activating the `change` event) or detect the change another way (`MutationObservers` wont work on forms)

Comment: @Nevermore _"(`MutationObservers` wont work on forms) "_ Was not aware of this; are you sure?

Comment: @guest271314 there is a lot I'm not sure about javascript in general, but editing the textarea doesnt change the DOM AFAIK and so `MutationObservers` doesnt register anything

Comment: @Nevermore The original Question appears to be  becoming broader? Can you create a gist including all relevant `html`, `javascript`? Not certain how to reproduce `Error: Permission denied to access property "apply"`?

Comment: @guest271314 I think the question has expanded since I've pursued one solution (which is very close to working!), but ultimately I'm still interested in putting a listener in a `content_script` for when an `ajax` call changes a `textarea` (and doesn't activate the `onchange`) - now the trick is get `ajaxComplete`, injected code, to register a `change`. Here is a gist of most things, [gist](https://gist.github.com/polypmer/9e413616a299904f8f9288d2bb700d09) I hope it helps explain... otherwise the website i"m injecting into is here https://play.golang.org/

Comment: Why do you call `script.remove()`? Where is `jQuery` defined at `html` `document`?

Comment: @guest271314  jquery is defined at the beginning of the header, here I"ll include the header in a gist as well. I call `script.remove()`.. well I don't know, I'll try otherwise (I was injecting using a stackoverflow answer...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery `.val(value)` does does dispatch `change` event. Call `.change()` or `.trigger("change")`.

If you do not know when `setBody` will be called you can use `.ajaxStop()` to call `.change()` on `$(opts.codeEl)` when last `$.ajax()` call completes.

```js
$(function() {

  let opts = {
    codeEl: document.querySelector("textarea")
  }

  $(opts.codeEl).on("change", function(event) {
    console.log("changed")
  });

  function setBody(text) {
    $(opts.codeEl).val(text)
  }

  let url = URL.createObjectURL(
    new Blob([
      JSON.stringify({
        "Body": "Hello World",
        "Error": ""
      })
    ], {
      type: "application/json"
    })
  );

  $.get(url)
  .then(function(data) {
    URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    setBody(JSON.stringify(data))
  });
  
  $(document).ajaxComplete(function(event, jqxhr, options) {
    if (options.url === url) {
      console.log("ajaxStop");
      $(opts.codeEl).change(); // trigger `change` event
    }
    
  });

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<textarea></textarea>
```

Comment: @guest271314 so `ajaxComplete` will trigger whenever an ajax request comes through? Even when the ajax request is sent and received in foreign code?

Comment: @Nevermore What do you mean by "foreign code"? Can you include all relevant `javascript` at Question?

Comment: @Nevermore, yes it'll always execute but you can simply compare the old textarea value with the current one. Also, you'll have to hook ajaxComplete in a [DOM-injected script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9517879).

Comment: @guest271314 so I"ve updated my question to specify that the ajax call is happening in an isolated script from my content script -- I think wOxxOm is onto something, but I need to first understand the code you put up before I can really get what "hook"ing an `ajaxComplete` function means... Basically, I need to inject that listener you've written above into the isolated script?

Comment: If you have control over the `html` `document`, you can inject the `.ajaxComplete()` portion of Answer at the `document`. Or, simply chain `.change()` to `.val()`. You could also try using [`chrome.webRequest`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest), [WebRequest API](http://www.adambarth.com/experimental/crx/docs/webRequest.html) from extension.

Comment: So, I've injected the ajax handler, and I successfully can check for the response, but I get an error: `Error: Permission denied to access property apply` when I call change. 2. I would like to simply chain `.change()` to `.val()` but the val change is happening inside a `src` script, so I don't know how to change it

Comment: _"but the val change is happening inside a src script, so I don't know how to change it"_ Not sure what you mean? Can you create a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net or plnkr http://plnkr.co to demonstrate? Did you call `.change()` on `<textarea>` element at `.ajaxComplete()`?

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not sure how to create a fiddle with an ajax request; I am calling `.change()` on the div in question on the `ajaxComplete()`, and it works, but I get a permission denied error which has something to do with cross site scripting  I think. I'll update my question with the modified code, if that helps

Comment: the problem with jsfiddle is that I'm injecting the js; It does work, but I'm unable to call `.change()` with injected code. I think. I;ll continue trying to make a demo with `echo`. Thanks