# Setting background-color of select options in JQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I have a page with multiple select boxes, as per the following:

```
<select name="item-0-status" id="id_item-0-status">
<option value="">---------</option>
<option value="1">Online</option>
<option value="2">Offline</option>
<option value="3">Unknown</option>
</select>
```

These are being auto-generated in django, so it is not possible to apply css classes, ids or attributes directly to the options. The select elements have ids of 'item-0-status','item-1-status','item-2-status' etc.

How can I add css colours to the options using the id of the select element?

I have tried to follow the code here: [How do you select a particular option in a SELECT element in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/314636/how-do-you-select-a-particular-option-in-a-select-element-in-jquery)

This has lead me to do, e.g. the following for setting 'offline' options to red:

```
$('select[id$=-status][id^=id_item-]').children().find('option[value="2"]').css('background-color','#FF0000');
```

but this has no effect.

How can I make this work? I realise support for this varies between browsers, but this is not an issue. For the purposes of this question working in Firefox 3.6 is enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like should work though note that I am not so sure.

```
$(function(){   

$('#id_item-0-status').children().each(
        function (){
            if($(this).val() == 2){
                $(this).css({'background':'red'});
            }
        }
);

})
```

Comment: this works, thanks, but any idea how I can now set the background colour of the selects to that of the selected options? I've tried $('select[id$=-status][id^=id_item-]').css({'background':$('option:selected',this).css('background')});

Comment: or,better (but still not working):$('select[id$=-status][id^=id_item-]').each(function(){$(this).css({'background':$('option:selected',this).css('background')});});

Comment: never mind, I have asked this as a separate question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5068087/set-background-colour-of-select-to-selected-option-in-jquery

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo.

It should be background-color. You have missed 'r'

Comment: well spotted and corrected - but still doesn't work, unfortunately