# How to make a drop down list with insted of strings we have block of colors

Tags: html, css

I want to have a drop down list in which I want four colors blocks to be displayed like as follows:

```
<select>
 <option> Black color </option>
 <option> Green color </option>
 <option> Yellow color</option>
 <option> pink color  </option>
</select>
```

Is it possible to do something like this..?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set background colour of select to selected option in JQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5068087/set-background-colour-of-select-to-selected-option-in-jquery)

Comment: @andyb its fairly different and this question does not include jquery

Comment: @Drake but the jQuery tag was until it was removed!

Answer (score 0):

Try this [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Matdy/)

```
<select>
  <option style="background-color:#000;color:white"> Black color </option>
  <option style="background-color:Green"> Green color </option>
  <option style="background-color:Yellow"> Yellow color</option>
  <option style="background-color:Pink"> pink color  </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would like just color based selections, then you can use this example
http://jsfiddle.net/cFtwe/

It sets all the colors using hex (you can use rgb as well)
Then using css it sets the width of the element since it will not have text to auto expand.

Comment: but when i select a color i want the menu box should also get colored.