# Changing the DIV and SELECT background colors at the same time

Tags: javascript

I need your help,

How can I, using the existing code below, also change the background of the surrounding DIV color to #FFFFC4? and then back to #FFFFFF?

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="select_wrapper"><select id="action"></select></div>
```

Code:

```
var y = document.getElementsByTagName('SELECT');

    for (var i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {

            y[i].onblur = function() {
                this.style.backgroundColor = '#FFFFFF'
            }

            y[i].onfocusin = function() {
                this.style.backgroundColor = '#FFFFC4'
            }
    }//end for
```

Comment: this.parentNode.style.backgroundColor = '#ffffc4'

Comment: simple method and flawless work :) Thanks so much Keith :)

Comment: Check out this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5068087/set-background-colour-of-select-to-selected-option-in-jquery/5068411#5068411

Comment: @KeithLantz That should be posted as an answer.