# Apply different style to the selected item of the asp:DropDownList

Tags: c#, jquery, css, asp.net

I want to **style the selected item of the asp:DropDownList**, the rest of the item may have default or some other style. Note that here **Selected Item means the item which is finally visible after the selection is made**.

I have used:

```
ddlID.Items[0].Attributes.CssStyle.Add("background-color", "yellow");

$("#ddlID option:first").css("background-color", "yellow");

ddlID.SelectedItem.Attributes.CssStyle.Add("background-color", "yellow");

$("#ddlID option:selected").css("background-color", "yellow");
```

None of the above worked for me the first two style the first item of the list and the last two style the item which is been selected in the list only.

I would **prefer CSS** to accomplish the task if possible.

Comment: Change the background color of dropdownlist element and not the listitem based on selection.

Comment: Looks like a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/q/8619406/728795

Comment: No its not, they talking about html element <select>. Here I am using asp control DropDownList and bind the items dynamically to it using server side code. Also if I use **option:checked** it changes the style of the respective item in the list only.

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5068087/set-background-colour-of-select-to-selected-option-in-jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all you guys for all those important links and hints. Finally, I got the solution so I thought to share it over here.
I have just added a class to the *asp:DropDownList* '**ddlStyle**' added all the style to this class which I wanted to be there on the selected item *(visible on the top after the selection is made)*.

```
.ddlStyle{
   background-color:yellow;
}
```

and added **option** to define the other css properties for the list of the items of the asp:DropDownList

```
.ddlStyle option{
   background-color:whitesmoke;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Below snippet:

**In CSS**

```
 <style>
        option:checked {
            background-color: yellow;
            color: red;
        }
    </style>
```

**In Aspx page**

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Text="-- Select --" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="ListItem1" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="ListItem2" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="ListItem3" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="ListItem4" Value="4"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```