# Toggle option color while click (whether dropdown is visible or not)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

In my example, there is two `select` tag where if I click any option from the first `select` then it's corresponding options will be shown in second `select`. My requirement is to set `color` in the `options` of all select while user will click(`eg: green`) on any. And if the user click on any selected option then that color will be gone(`white`). That means a toggle of color regarding selection(also any appearance of `tick mark` also acceptable). I have thought it because it will give the user a tracking on the basis of the color while right no there is no opportunity like that.

A combination I am writing here(This toggle color is only for the `second select`):
If I rewrite the steps(I am thinking to modufy the post by the following lines):
`STEP_1:`  user chosen `0001_Summer` and automatically `row_heat_0` is selected(I don't know how to disable this. if can disable it also a good leap) and color will be `green` for this option.

`STEP_2:`  if user again click on `row_heat_0` the color will turn to `white`(that means not selected).

`STEP_3:`  if user now click on `row_heat_1` the color will turn to `green` for this option.

`STEP_4:`  if user now click on `row_heat_0` the color will turn to `green` for this option as well. Now if user select `All` then that option will be in `green color` So, in this stage there is `2 option` is `green` in `second select` and they are `row_heat_0`, `row_heat_1` and `All`. Also in the `first select` one option is `green` and that is `0001_Summer`.

`STEP_5:`  if user now change the `first select` option to `0003_Spring` and do some `select/not_select` operation also same affect will be seen.

`STEP_6:`  if user turn to `0001_Summer` still the seleted will be seen in `green` color(`row_heat_0`, `row_heat_1`, `All`).

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5068087/set-background-colour-of-select-to-selected-option-in-jquery) but failed to see any change.

I am giving teh whole code where I want to apply it

```js
    data = {
  "0001_Summer": {
    "param": [
      "Select_Param",
      "row_heat_0",
      "row_heat_1",
      "row_heat_2",
      "row_heat_3",
      "row_heat_4",
      "row_heat_5",
      "row_heat_6",
      "All"
    ],
    "value": [
      "Select_Param",
      "value_00",
      "value_01",
      "value_02",
      "value_03",
      "value_04",
      "value_05",
      "value_06",
      "All"
    ]
  },
  "0002_Winter": {
    "param": [
      "Select_Param",
      "row_cloud_0",
      "row_cloud_1",
      "row_cloud_2",
      "row_cloud_3",
      "row_cloud_4",
      "row_cloud_5",
      "row_cloud_6",
      "row_cloud_7",
      "row_cloud_8",
      "All"
    ],
    "value": [
      "Select_Param",
      "value_00",
      "value_01",
      "value_02",
      "value_03",
      "value_04",
      "value_05",
      "value_06",
      "value_07",
      "value_08",
      "All"
    ]
  },
  "0003_Spring": {
    "param": [
      "Select_Param",
      "row_color_0",
      "row_color_1",
      "row_color_2",
      "row_color_3",
      "row_color_4",
      "All"
    ],
    "value": [
      "Select_Param",
      "value_00",
      "value_01",
      "value_02",
      "value_03",
      "value_04",
      "All"
    ]
  },
  "0004_Autumn": {
    "param": [
      "Select_Param",
      "dev_x_0",
      "dev_x_1",
      "dev_x_2",
      "dev_x_3",
      "All"
    ],
    "value": [
      "Select_Param",
      "value_00",
      "value_01",
      "value_02",
      "value_03",
      "All"
    ]
  }
}


function make_option_1(data, select, value, value_1 = null) {
  option = $("<option>")
    .attr({
      text: data,
      value: value,
      value_1: value_1
    }).html(data);
  select.append(option);
}

let temp_json = [];
let json_for_backend = {};

function make_dropdown_1(data) {
  var select_device = document.getElementById("device_n");
  var select_name = document.getElementById("name_n");

  var jqr_select_device = $(select_device);
  var jqr_select_name = $(select_name);

  for (let a in data) {
    make_option_1(a, jqr_select_device, a);
    for (let b = 0; b < Object.keys(data[a]["param"]).length; b++) {
      make_option_1(data[a]["param"][b], jqr_select_name, a, b);
    }
  }
  $("#device_n").trigger('change') //call first select
}

$("#device_n").change(function() {
  var id = $(this).val();
  let init_name_n_val = $("#name_n option:selected").val();
  $("#name_n option").hide() //hide all options
  $("#name_n option[value='" + id + "']").show(); //show options where value matches
  $("#name_n option[value_1=0][value='" + id + "']").prop('selected', true); //set second value selected
  
  if($(this).val() == "select device"){
  $("#name_n").val("select parameter");
  }
  else{
  $("#name_n").trigger('change'); //call second select
  }
});

$("#name_n").change(function() {
  var values = $("#device_n").val();
  let name_n_option_text = $( "#name_n option:selected").text();
  let name_n_option_index = data[values]["param"].indexOf(name_n_option_text);
  let updated_value = data[values]["value"][name_n_option_index];
  let value_key = "value";
  if (updated_value != "Select_Param") {
    create_json_for_backend(values, value_key, updated_value);
}
});

make_dropdown_1(data);


function create_json_for_backend(main_key,value_key, updated_value){
if (!json_for_backend.hasOwnProperty(main_key))
{
    var value_temp_json = {};
    var value_temp_list = [];
    value_temp_list.push(updated_value);
    value_temp_json[String(value_key)] = value_temp_list;
    json_for_backend[String(main_key)] = value_temp_json;
}
else{
    if(!json_for_backend[main_key][value_key].includes(updated_value)){
    json_for_backend[main_key][value_key].push(updated_value);
  }
}
}

let input = $("<input>")
                    .attr("id", "id_for_input")
                    .attr('type', 'number')
                    .attr('name', 'value')
                    .attr('placeholder','query')
                    .addClass("all_input_class");
          
submit_button = $("<button>")
                    .addClass("class_for_submit")
                    .text('Submit')
                    .click(function() {
                            var inputVal = document.getElementById("id_for_input").value;
                        json_for_backend["Query"] = inputVal;
                        console.log(json_for_backend);
                    });

let get_div = document.getElementsByClassName("container");
let get_div_jquery = $(get_div);
get_div_jquery.append(input, submit_button);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>JSON Form</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body id="body" style="margin-top: 0">
  <div class="container" style="margin-top:100px;">
      <label for="combination">make combination:</label>
      <select name="device_n" id="device_n" init_text = "ini">
        <option selected="selected" class="grey_color" >select device</option>
      </select>
      <select name="name_n" id="name_n" init_text = "ini">
        <option selected="selected" class="grey_color" >select parameter</option>
      </select>
  </div> 
  
</body>
</html>
```

So, finally I can again repeat that I need an idea to design a system where user can click on any option and it will toggle the color of that option(also any appearance of `tick mark` also acceptable).

**I found the combination I have given in the upper part is not that much understandable so I am adding here few lines**

`I am trying to clarify more. Consider`green`color as`tick mark`(just for clarifying). User can select multiple option then` tick mark`will appear in those selected options. If user again click on any seletced option where already`tick mark`is appeared then that`tick mark`will be gone. Just now, replace`tick mark`with the`green color`and disappearance of`tick mark`with`white color`. That means user can see which options are selected by seeing the` tick mark`or a`color`. Eg:` 0001_Summer`selected and then selected`row_heat_0`and ,`row_heat_0`and`row_heat_2`that means user will see these 3 options has`green`color. Then if user again click on`row_heat_1`then this option will be white and user will see`row_heat_0`and`row_heat_2`are`green`now. user will now choose`0002_Winter `and select some options there(`eg: row_cloud_0, row_cloud_1, row_cloud_4`) and all those 3 options will be green. if Now user again choose` 0001_Summer`the options`row_heat_0`and`row_heat_2`are still green. That means a feeling of tracking user can have.`

Comment: Hi, you said `it's corresponding second select row_heat_0 will be green..` but if user select that again it will remove that green colour , but what will happen if user load option again by changing option from first option so `row_heat_0` will be in green color or not ?

Comment: if I don't misunderstand your comment then answer is `will be in green color`. I want to see in `gren color` any option which I have selected. And then I can decide whether I will deselect it or not and color changing will make it simpler visually. I have modified the `STEPS` in question. Hopefully it will be more clear now.

Comment: :P No , what i mean to say is if user unselect `row_heat_0`(change color to white) then when this options will get loaded again  `row_heat_0` will be green color or white ? because first option is default selected (set to green).

Comment: Then it should be `white`. Actually that's why I have written `I don't know how to disable this. if can disable it also a good leap`. I am thinking on it by adding extra `key` is JSON but which is obviously ot an `optimum solution`.

Comment: @Swati I have modified the JSON architecture. Now by default any `row_*` will not be selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get  option which is selected by user using `(this).find("option:selected")` and then use `addClass` & `removeClass` classes from your select-box options to change color .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
data = {
  "0001_Summer": {
    "param": [
      "Select_Param",
      "row_heat_0",
      "row_heat_1",
      "row_heat_2",
      "row_heat_3",
      "row_heat_4",
      "row_heat_5",
      "row_heat_6",
      "All"
    ],
    "value": [
      "Select_Param",
      "value_00",
      "value_01",
      "value_02",
      "value_03",
      "value_04",
      "value_05",
      "value_06",
      "All"
    ]
  },
  "0002_Winter": {
    "param": [
      "Select_Param",
      "row_cloud_0",
      "row_cloud_1",
      "row_cloud_2",
      "row_cloud_3",
      "row_cloud_4",
      "row_cloud_5",
      "row_cloud_6",
      "row_cloud_7",
      "row_cloud_8",
      "All"
    ],
    "value": [
      "Select_Param",
      "value_00",
      "value_01",
      "value_02",
      "value_03",
      "value_04",
      "value_05",
      "value_06",
      "value_07",
      "value_08",
      "All"
    ]
  },
  "0003_Spring": {
    "param": [
      "Select_Param",
      "row_color_0",
      "row_color_1",
      "row_color_2",
      "row_color_3",
      "row_color_4",
      "All"
    ],
    "value": [
      "Select_Param",
      "value_00",
      "value_01",
      "value_02",
      "value_03",
      "value_04",
      "All"
    ]
  },
  "0004_Autumn": {
    "param": [
      "Select_Param",
      "dev_x_0",
      "dev_x_1",
      "dev_x_2",
      "dev_x_3",
      "All"
    ],
    "value": [
      "Select_Param",
      "value_00",
      "value_01",
      "value_02",
      "value_03",
      "All"
    ]
  }
}


function make_option_1(data, select, value, value_1 = null) {
  option = $("<option>")
    .attr({
      text: data,
      value: value,
      value_1: value_1
    }).html(data);
  select.append(option);
}

let temp_json = [];
let json_for_backend = {};

function make_dropdown_1(data) {
  var select_device = document.getElementById("device_n");
  var select_name = document.getElementById("name_n");

  var jqr_select_device = $(select_device);
  var jqr_select_name = $(select_name);

  for (let a in data) {
    make_option_1(a, jqr_select_device, a);
    for (let b = 0; b < Object.keys(data[a]["param"]).length; b++) {
      make_option_1(data[a]["param"][b], jqr_select_name, a, b);
    }
  }
  $("#device_n").trigger('change') //call first select
}

$("#device_n").change(function() {
  var id = $(this).val();
  let init_name_n_val = $("#name_n option:selected").val();

  $("#name_n option").hide() //hide all options
  $("#name_n option[value='" + id + "']").show();
  $("#name_n option[value_1=0][value='" + id + "']").prop('selected', true);
  if ($(this).val() == "select device") {
    $("#name_n").val("select parameter");
  } else {
    $("#device_n option").removeClass("selected") //remove from others
    $(this).find("option:selected").addClass("selected") //add selected 
    $("#name_n").trigger('change'); //call second select

  }
});

$("#name_n").change(function() {
  var values = $("#device_n").val();
  let name_n_option_text = $("#name_n option:selected").text();
  //not the first option
  if ($(this).find("option:selected").attr("text") != "Select_Param" && !$(this).find("option:selected").hasClass("selected")) {
    $(this).find("option:selected").addClass("selected") //add selected
  } else {
    $(this).find("option:selected").removeClass("selected") //remove 
  }

  //let ..
  //create_json_for_backend(values, value_key, updated_value);
});

make_dropdown_1(data);
```

```css
.selected {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="device_n" id="device_n" init_text="ini">
  <option selected="selected" class="grey_color">select device</option>
</select>
<select name="name_n" id="name_n" init_text="ini">
  <option selected="selected" class="grey_color">select parameter</option>
</select>
```

***Update 1*** :

You can use `selectpicker` plugin which already has this functionality so all code will remain same just some minor changes you need to make in your current code.

***Update code*** :

```js
var data = {
  "0001_Summer": {
    "param": [
      "Select_Param",
      "row_heat_0",
      "row_heat_1",
      "row_heat_2",
      "row_heat_3",
      "row_heat_4",
      "row_heat_5",
      "row_heat_6",
      "All"
    ],
    "value": [
      "Select_Param",
      "value_00",
      "value_01",
      "value_02",
      "value_03",
      "value_04",
      "value_05",
      "value_06",
      "All"
    ]
  },
  "0002_Winter": {
    "param": [
      "Select_Param",
      "row_cloud_0",
      "row_cloud_1",
      "row_cloud_2",
      "row_cloud_3",
      "row_cloud_4",
      "row_cloud_5",
      "row_cloud_6",
      "row_cloud_7",
      "row_cloud_8",
      "All"
    ],
    "value": [
      "Select_Param",
      "value_00",
      "value_01",
      "value_02",
      "value_03",
      "value_04",
      "value_05",
      "value_06",
      "value_07",
      "value_08",
      "All"
    ]
  },
  "0003_Spring": {
    "param": [
      "Select_Param",
      "row_color_0",
      "row_color_1",
      "row_color_2",
      "row_color_3",
      "row_color_4",
      "All"
    ],
    "value": [
      "Select_Param",
      "value_00",
      "value_01",
      "value_02",
      "value_03",
      "value_04",
      "All"
    ]
  },
  "0004_Autumn": {
    "param": [
      "Select_Param",
      "dev_x_0",
      "dev_x_1",
      "dev_x_2",
      "dev_x_3",
      "All"
    ],
    "value": [
      "Select_Param",
      "value_00",
      "value_01",
      "value_02",
      "value_03",
      "All"
    ]
  }
}

function make_option(data, select, value, value_1 = null) {
  option = $("<option>")
    .attr({
      text: data,
      value: value,
      value_1: value_1
    }).html(data);
  select.append(option);
}

let temp_json = []; // no need here, test purpose for future
let json_for_backend = {}; // no need here, test purpose for future
var data_new = {}; // no need here, test purpose for future

function make_dropdown(data) {
  var select_device = document.getElementById("device_n");
  var select_name = document.getElementById("name_n");

  var jqr_select_device = $(select_device);
  var jqr_select_name = $(select_name);

  for (let a in data) {
    make_option(a, jqr_select_device, a);
    for (let b = 0; b < Object.keys(data[a]["param"]).length; b++) {
      make_option(data[a]["param"][b], jqr_select_name, a, b);
    }
  }
  data_new = data;
  $('#device_n').selectpicker('refresh'); // NEWLY ADDED
  $("#device_n").trigger('change') //call first select
}

$("#device_n").change(function() {
  var id = $(this).val();
  console.log("id: ", id);
  let init_name_n_val = $("#name_n option:selected").val();

  $("#name_n option").hide() //hide all options
  $("#name_n option[value='" + id + "']").show();
  if ($(this).val() == "select device") {
    //$("#name_n").val("select parameter");
  } else {
    $('#name_n').selectpicker('refresh'); //call second select

  }
});
//on change of second select-box
$('#name_n').on('changed.bs.select', function(event, clickedIndex, newValue, oldValue) {
  //get value of clicked option
  var selected_text = $("#name_n option").eq(clickedIndex).text();
  console.log("selected_text: ", selected_text);
});

make_dropdown(data);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.4/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.4/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>


<div class="container" style="margin-top:100px;">
  <label for="combination">make combination:</label>
  <select name="device_n" id="device_n" class="selectpicker">
    <option selected="selected" class="grey_color">select device</option>
  </select>
  <select name="name_n" id="name_n" class="selectpicker" multiple>
  </select>

</div>
```

Comment: I have tried it but unfortunately no chnage I have seen in the `option / options` while I have seletct and deselect. Also here in the `code snippet` after running no change is showing.

Comment: When you select any option it will change color to green you will see that when you open select-box again because after change event we are setting color or you need some other behaviour ?

Comment: I actually need something different. maybe my description was not helpful. I am trying to clarify more. Consider `green` color as `tick mark`(just for clarifying). User can select multiple option then `tick mark` will appear in those selected options. If user again click on any seletced option where already `tick mark` is appeared then that `tick mark` will be gone. Just now, replace `tick mark` with the `green color` and disappearance of `tick mark` with `white color`. That means user can see which options are selected by seeing the `tick mark` or a `color`. Edited Ques as it is too long

Comment: Please see the last part of the question, I have edited it to clarify with example.

Comment: Sorry but , i am able to see option are working fine (changing color) :/ so i am little bit confuse why you are not able to see that .

Comment: that means if you select `0001_Summer` and then `row_heat_0`, `row_heat_1` and `All` can you see these three `options` are in `green` color? And if you click on `All` then `green` color appears on `row_heat_0` and `row_heat_1` while all the other options in dropdown is `white`(while whole dropdown is visible then it can you see?)? I cannot see anything in my `browser` or in the `code snippet` like that. using `Firefox`.

Comment: Check in chrome and see onces.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232591/discussion-between-swati-and-user10634362).