# How to select dropdown list using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have the dropdown below. I want to populate orange in the dropdown when the page loads. I made a function, PopulateDropDown, which runs the jQuery code to do so, but it is not working.

```
<select name="cboFruits" id="cboFruits">
    <option value="Apple">Apple</option>
    <option value="Orange">Orange</option>
    <option value="Mango">Mango</option>
    <option value="Banana">Banana</option>
    <option value="Pine">Pine</option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript" src ="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
    function PopulateDropDown(pFruitName)
    {
        $('cboFruits :selected').val(pFruitName);
    }

    $(document).ready(function(){
        PopulateDropDown('Orange');
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to write ** # ** and remove **selected**

```
$('#cboFruits').val(pFruitName);
```

**EDIT :**

or you use

```
<option value="Orange" selected="true">Orange</option>
```

when page by default **'Orange'** will be selected

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are a few problems with your code:

```
 $('cboFruits :selected').val(pFruitName);
```

First of all, you're missing the # in front of cboFruits, since cboFruits is the ID property of your select list.

Also the correct way of setting the selected option would be something like this:

```
function PopulateDropDown(pFruitName)
{
    $('#cboFruits option:contains("'+pFruitName+'")').prop('selected', true);
}

$(document).ready(function(){   
    PopulateDropDown('Orange');
});​
```

Ref this question [How do you select a particular option in a SELECT element in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/314636/how-do-you-select-a-particular-option-in-a-select-element-in-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

It should work:

```
function PopulateDropDown(pFruitName)
{
    $('#cboFruits').val(pFruitName);
}
```