# trying to select value of a select box with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I looked at [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/314636/how-do-you-select-a-particular-option-in-a-select-element-in-jquery) but couldn't implement it. I wonder if I am missing something else.

Note: `response.user_data['admin']` is not null. I checked.

Any ideas?

Thanks

**DIDN'T WORK LINES**

```
$('#select_administrator option[value="'+response.user_data['admin']+'"]');
$('#select_administrator option:eq('+response.user_data['admin']+')').attr('selected', 'selected');
$('#select_administrator option:eq('+response.user_data['admin']+')').prop('selected', true);
```

**HTML**

```
<select id="select_administrator" name="select_administrator">
    <option value="NO" <?php echo ($administrator == 'NO') ? 'selected="selected"' : null; ?>>NO</option>
        <option value="YES" <?php echo ($administrator == 'YES') ? 'selected="selected"' : null; ?>>YES</option>
</select>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
   $("#select_user").change(function(event)
   {
      event.preventDefault();

      var selected_user = null;
      selected_user = $(this).val();

      $.ajax({
                 type       : "POST",
                 url        : 'mypage.php',
                 data       : {select_user:selected_user},
                 dataType   : "json",
                 success        : function(response)
         {
            if(response.status == "success")
                    {
                        $("#form_errors_jquery").hide();

                        $("#text_username").val(response.user_data['username']);

                        //response.user_data['admin'];
                        //Should select admin combo here

        //$('#select_administrator option[value="'+response.user_data['admin']+'"]');
        //$('#select_administrator option:eq('+response.user_data['admin']+')').attr('selected', 'selected');
        //$('#select_administrator option:eq('+response.user_data['admin']+')').prop('selected', true);

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $("#form_errors_jquery").html(response.error).fadeIn(1000);
                    }
         },
                 error      : function(response)
                 {
                     $("#form_errors_jquery").html("A network error occured").fadeIn(1000);
         }

      return false;
   });
});
```

Comment: Define "didn't work".  FYI, I believe you can simply do `$('#select_administrator').val('YES');`

Comment: Auto selection doesn't happen. No errors too.

Comment: Can you also post the response data?

Answer (score 0):

Well for starters, your jquery is selecting this when it changes `$("#select_user").change(function(event)`
but your html is `<select id="select_administrator" name="select_administrator">` so you might want to select the correct id of the select element and try again.

Further, both of these work in a jsfiddle with your HTML. Either your response.user_data['admin'] has spaces, or is not coming back correctly formatted is my guess.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#select_administrator option[value="NO"]').prop('selected', true); 
});​

$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#select_administrator option[value="NO"]').attr('selected','selected'); 
});​
```

Edit:
I've made a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pf2Dq/) that boiled down the code above with what you're trying to do, and these two options didn't work at all:

```
 $('#select_administrator option:eq('+response.user_data['admin']+')').attr('selected', 'selected');
 $('#select_administrator option:eq('+response.user_data['admin']+')').prop('selected', true);
```

But if you add the attr('selected', 'selected'); to the first try to make it look like this:

```
$('#select_administrator option[value="'+response.user_data['admin']+'"]').attr('selected', 'selected');
```

it works fine. Try it out and let me know?

Comment: `response.user_data['admin']` returns either YES or NO without spaces. I'l alert()'ing it to double check. ID attribute of the field is also correct.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the issue I ended up using  this code instead but why original code above doesn't work?

```
if (response.user_data['admin'] == 'YES')
{
    $('#select_administrator').val('YES');
}
else
{
    $('#select_administrator').val('NO');
}
```