# Finding an option in a select element, and selecting it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My problem is pretty much syntax related, I'm sure.

I have a page, on which there are tags (buttons). The user should be able to click on one of those tags to edit it's name.

Also on that same page, I have a select list in which I keep track of all the changes. My problem arises when I click the tag button, and the corresponding option in the list should be selected dynamically. I tried several things, here's my latest attempt:

HTML

```
       <!-- tags container -->
        <div class="container_12">
            <div class="grid_2"><img src="images/spacer.png" /></div>
            <div id="content" class="grid_8">
                <button name="PHP" class="tag-button" onclick="edit(this)">PHP</button>
            </div>
            <div class="grid_2"><img src="images/spacer.png" /></div>
        </div>
        <!-- tags container end -->

        <!-- action buttons container -->
        <div class="container_12 action-bar">
            <div class="grid_4"><img src="images/spacer.png" /></div>
            <div id="action-add">
                <input type="text" name="newTag" id="newTag" />
                <input type="button" id="add" value="Add tag" />
            </div>
            <div class="grid_4"><img src="images/spacer.png" /></div>
            <div id="action-edit">
                <input type="text" name="editTag" id="editTag" />
                <input type="button" id="update" value="Update tag" />
            </div>
         <!-- action buttons container end -->
        </div>

        <!-- Real Time list container -->
        <div class="container_12">
            <div class="grid_4"><img src="images/spacer.png" /></div>
            <select id="insertString" multiple>
                <option value="0">PHP</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <!-- real time list container end -->
```

Javascript/jquery:

```
    //function edit: places the tag button info in textbox
    function edit(element)
    {
            var name = $(element).attr('name');
            //add the tag name to the editTag textbox
            $('#editTag').val(name);
            //find in the list the corresponding option, and select it
            $('#insertString').find('option: contains("' + name + '")').attr("selected", true);
     }
```

The portion of code I'm concerned with right now, is the "find in the list the corresponding option, and select it." I can't seem to make it select the option at all.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: try this: `$('#insertString').find('option: contains("' + name + '")').prop("selected", true);`

Comment: I just tried this, and the item in the list still isn't getting selected...

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/314636/how-do-you-select-a-particular-option-in-a-select-element-in-jquery

Comment: I'm looking into the possible duplicate - thank you for bringing it to my attention.

Comment: @Emil Borconi the duplicate didn't help with my situation... sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var previous = "Gateway 1", edited = "world";
$('#insertString option:contains("' + previous +'")').text(edited);
$('#insertString option:contains("'+ edited + '")').attr('selected', true);
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gWnu5/1/)

Comment: It still isn't getting selected, after changing my code to this - sorry. I even had tried this before... to no avail

Comment: I don't understand... your fiddle works fine, but when I try it on my end - it just doesn't. would it be because my select is multiple?

Comment: No that wont effect. Because I tried duplicating the values

Comment: I could try using a normal select - but I would prefer keeping it as a multiple if it's possible

Comment: are you trying to change the value of options ? and then making it selected

Comment: what I'd like is to be able to: 1) select the item in the list, to keep track of the tag being edited. 2) once edited, the item in the list itself will be updated with the new name.

Comment: I just tried changing my select to a normal one, and it still won't get selected... I'm in a twilight zone episode, I'm sure

Comment: I've just tried this but I run into an issue with timing. Your code supposes that I would already have the edited value when the user clicks edit - but I do not. I only get that value once the user clicks update... which is the next step. The update step I feel I could make work, as I've done this before - it's only the handling of the list I'm having issues with

Comment: can u show me how the UI looks like, things look messy with out seeing any thing

Comment: I'm making a fiddle... it's my first time playing around with jsfiddle so bear with me :)

Comment: where is the fiddle ?

Answer (score 0):

```
//function edit: places the tag button info in textbox
    function edit(element)
    {
            var name = $(element).attr('name');
            //add the tag name to the editTag textbox
            $('#editTag').val(name);
            //find in the list the corresponding option, and select it
            $('#insertString').val('"+name+"');
     }
```

Comment: still zero joy... sorry

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the following:

```
$('#insertString').find('option:contains("'+ name + '")').attr("selected", true);
```

Comment: this is the very first thing I tried, but I think the fact my select is a multiple select is the reason why it fails. Any idea how to make this work with a multiple select would be great

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#insertString option[value='" + name "']").prop('selected', true);
```

Comment: I have a feeling the fact my select is a multiple select box, is the reason these answers aren't working - any idea how to make this work with a multiple select?