# How to hide an option value

Tags: jquery

I have tried everything i know to remove some of these option values

here is the html - I want to remove every option that has a value with MESSAGE in it

```
<select id="source_list" name="HOME_MODULES_AVAILABLE" size="16">
 <option value="TWITTER_FEED=N"></option>
 <option value="MFLTIP=N"></option>
 <option value="WHO_SHOULD_I_START=N"></option>
 <option value="LEAGUE_MAP=W"></option>
 <option value="MESSAGE=W"></option>
 <option value="MESSAGE2=W"></option>
 <option value="MESSAGE3=W"></option>
 <option value="MESSAGE4=W"></option>
```

I have tried all of these and no luck

```
$('#source_list:contains("MESSAGE")').hide();
$("option:contains('MESSAGE')").hide();
$("#source_list option[value="MESSAGE"]").hide();
$("select > option[value*='MESSAGE']").remove();
$("select > option[value$='MESSAGE']").remove();
$("#source_list > option[value*='MESSAGE']").remove();
```

any advice ?

Comment: Please check: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6068322/3834042

Comment: Your last line seems to work for me and removes last 4 options. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5y5z94f9/).

Comment: izstas , your correct !! i had a syntax error on my trial page when i tried that one ;) Thanks

Comment: can you try with `filter` ?

Comment: like `$("#source_list > option").filter(function( i , v ){ return /MESSAGE/.test( v.value );})`

Comment: @MShack: Please check the answer i ve provided, and  select the answer which works well for u, so that the question does not go unanswered.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#source_list option').each(function(i, e) {
    if($(e).attr('value').match(/^MESSAGE/)) $(e).remove();
});
```

It iterates through every option node and checks with a regular expression, whether value starts with "MESSAGE".

It is by the way better to remove the options instead of trying to hide them, due to better cross browser support.

Comment: "When should I vote down? Use your downvotes whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect." What of this is the reason for your downvote(s)?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this

1) **starts with selector ^** - it checks for all options value starting with the word MESSAGE.

```
$("#source_list > option[value^='MESSAGE']").remove();
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/0d44sjyo/)**

2) **contains selector *** - it checks for all options value containing the word MESSAGE.

```
$("#source_list > option[value*='MESSAGE']").remove();
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/0d44sjyo/1/)**

Answer (score -1):

Try using CSS:

```
option[value="MESSAGE"] {
    display:none;
}
```

If you want it to be toggle-able add the following class to the option tags you want to be able to hide and show.

```
.hidden {
    display:none;
}
```

then use .addClass and .removeClass via jQuery.

Answer (score -2):

```
$("#selectboxid option[value='1']").remove();
```

Comment: it won't selected options with value `MESSAGE` in it .

Comment: which option you have to remove and that option value has to be place with in option