# How to make option select selected by jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

Here is my HTML.

```
<select class="height_selected" id="renderHeight">
    <option>Select Height</option>
    <option value="1">123 cm</option>
    <option value="2">125 cm</option>
</select>
```

I want to make the Option 2 i.e., 125 cm as selected.

I tried

`$('#1 :selected').text();`

But it is not working.

How can i make the option 125 selected i.e., value that have `#1` as selected

**Update i have another option select**

I want to make only the height to be selected.

```
<select class="weight_selected" id="renderWeight">
    <option>Select Weight</option>
    <option value="1">100 kg</option>
    <option value="2">125 kg</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `prop` to select the `option`.

```
$('#renderHeight option[value="2"]').prop('selected', true);
```

**Code Demo**

```js
$('option[value="2"]').prop('selected', true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="height_selected" id="renderHeight">
  <option>Select Height</option>
  <option value="1">123 cm</option>
  <option value="2">125 cm</option>
</select>
```

You can also set the value using `val()`.

```js
$('#renderHeight').val(2);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="height_selected" id="renderHeight">
  <option>Select Height</option>
  <option value="1">123 cm</option>
  <option value="2">125 cm</option>
</select>
```

Comment: @Vamsi: this post on SO should help you regarding the selection of the options by their value (assuming by "name" you meant the value/content?): http://stackoverflow.com/a/6068322/1901282

Answer (score 0):

Try this : To make option selected, you can directly set value of select box to the value of option to be selected.

```js
$(function(){
  $('#renderWeight').val('2');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="weight_selected"  id="renderWeight">
<option>Select Weight</option>
<option value="1">100 kg</option>
<option value="2">125 kg</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use val() by passing the option value

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ke5qjmro/)

```
$('#renderHeight').val(2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code

```js
$('#renderHeight option').each(function(){
  if($(this).text() =='123 cm'){
    $(this).prop('selected',true)
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="height_selected"  id="renderHeight">
<option>Select Height</option>
<option value="1">123 cm</option>
<option value="2">125 cm</option>
</select>
```