# How to change dropdown option and price together

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropdownbox

I have a select menu with multiple options. Using jQuery I was trying to pre-populate the dropdown. I've tried using this code:

```js
jQuery("select#attribute150").val("Double").click();
```

I can visually see that the option has been selected, however the actual price has not been changed. I've also tried:

```js
jQuery("select#attribute150").val("Double").change();
```

URL to the dropdown is [here](http://www.bensonsforbeds.co.uk/tempur-cloud-platinum-mattress/?variantSku=311900003). The dropdown I want to change is "Size".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you select a particular option in a SELECT element in jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/314636/how-do-you-select-a-particular-option-in-a-select-element-in-jquery)

Comment: You need some event handler for the change event for the select menu. Please show us this code.

Comment: It doesn't update the UI because you're not triggering the event that the code is listening for. What events have you bound to that select?

Comment: @this.lau_ I've tired that but it did not work, please test in console

Comment: on the given website , when i change the site the price is changing as expected. what is the issue ?

Comment: @Deep I am trying to do that through jQuery rather than physically clicking on it