# How to programmatically select an option inside a variable using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

Let say I have this variable html which contain these select options:

```
var html = '<select>'+
             '<option value="10">10</option>'+
             '<option value="20">20</option>'+
            '</select>';
```

How can I *programmatically* select an option which is inside the html variable so when I append them to somewhere, for example

```
$(this).children('div').append(html);
```

it will become like this:

```
<div> <!-- children div of the current scope -->
  <select>
    <option value="10" selected>10</option>
    <option value="20">20</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

How is it possible?

---

edit: the variable contents is generated from remote locations, and I must change the value locally before it is being appended into a div. Hence, the question.

edit 2: sorry for the confusion, question has been updated with my real situation.

Comment: You can append them and then update the selected property thereafter.

Comment: @Terry that's the part I'm stuck until now. mind to share some answer? (please) *wink-wink*

Comment: didnt this work ? var html = '<select><option value="10" selected>10</option><option value="20">20</option></select>'

Comment: This can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/314636/how-do-you-select-a-particular-option-in-a-select-element-in-jquery#comment46279592_6068322

Comment: @Terry the variable html is generated and I have no control over them

Comment: you could try simply setting the value of the drop-down to the one you wish to 'select' - like `$("#select_handle select").val( a_value );` - if `a_value` is 10 it will add the needed HTML to the DOM node

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can cast the HTML into a jQuery element and select the value at index 0. Then you can add it to the DOM.

Here is a simple jQuery plugin to select an option by index.

```js
(function($) {
  $.fn.selectOptionByIndex = function(index) {
    this.find('option:eq(' + index  + ')').prop('selected', true);
    return this;
  };
  $.fn.selectOptionByValue = function(value) {
    return this.val(value);
  };
  $.fn.selectOptionByText = function(text) {
    this.find('option').each(function() {
      $(this).attr('selected', $(this).text() == text);                                 
    });
    return this;
  };
})(jQuery);

var $html = $([
  '<select>',
    '<option value="10">10</option>',
    '<option value="20">20</option>',
  '</select>'
].join(''));

$('#select-handle').append($html.selectOptionByIndex(0));
// or
$html.selectOptionByValue(10);
// or
$html.selectOptionByText('10');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="select-handle"></div>
```

Comment: splendid. no any other words to say. $('#select-handle').append($html.selectOptionByIndex(0));
 <<<< this is what I'm looking for. thank you

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl cool solution... that's why I like SO so much - always gives you something to learn :)

Comment: just out of curiousity, would this statement `this.find('option:eq(' + index  + ')').prop('selected', true);` end up making multiple selected option?

Comment: @Jeffrey04 the `:eq()` part makes it select just the given index. If you set another one to selected, it will deselect the previous option, unless the `<select>` tag has the `multiple` property (which it doesn't in this case).

Answer (score 5):

You could try simply setting the value of the drop-down to the one you wish to 'select' - like 
`$("#select_handle select").val( a_value );`

For example, if `a_value` is 30 it will add the needed HTML to the DOM node. This would be my take:

```js
$(function() {
  var html = '<select>' +
      '<option value="10">10</option>' +
      '<option value="20">20</option>' +
      '<option value="30">30</option>' +
      '<option value="40">40</option>' +
      '<option value="50">50</option>' +
    '</select>';

  // set a value; must match a 'value' from the select or it will be ignored
  var a_value = 30; 

  // append select HTML
  $('#select_handle').append(html);

  // set a value; must match a 'value' from the select or it will be ignored
  $("#select_handle select").val(a_value);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h2>select added below</h2>
<div id="select_handle">
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

By default, the first *option* will be selected - if you want to do on any other set it so using the *index* as soon as the `select` is appended:

```
$('#select_handle option:eq(1)').prop('selected', true)
```

(this selects the second option)

See demo below:

```js
var html = '<select>'+
             '<option value="10">10</option>'+
             '<option value="20">20</option>'+
            '</select>';
$('#select_handle').append(html);
$('#select_handle option:eq(1)').prop('selected', true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="select_handle"></div>
```

Comment: can I select the option before the selectbox is being appended into #select_handle? thanks

Comment: @FarizLuqman normally I wait for the DOM to update and use something like `ng-init` (because I use angular) but *Mr. Polywhirl*'s answer is a new thing for me... :)

Comment: on normal times, I will also do that by using solutions my fellow friends provided before him (again sorry for not clearing the question) but to update the element *before* the DOM is updated, that may take some advanced level of understanding, and hence, a new lesson to be learned by all :)

Answer (score 3):

selected="selected" will work

```
var html = '<select>'+
             '<option value="10">10</option>'+
             '<option value="20" selected="selected">20</option>'+
            '</select>';

            $('#select_handle').append(html);
```

Comment: The variable html is completely generated by remote location, and the only choice I have is to modify the content of the variable.

Comment: $("#select_handle option[value=10]").attr('selected','selected'); will help

Answer (score 3):

You can do this in **jQuery** using the `.attr()` function and `nth` pseudo-selector.

Like so:

```
$("option:nth-child(1)").attr("selected", "");
```

Hope it helps! :-)

Answer (score 2):

after the append, try `$('#select_handle select').val("10");` or 20 or whatever value you want to select