# Selected option does not working through jquery

Tags: jquery, angularjs

This is my angular with JQuery

```
mainDodApp.controller('EditPageController', ['$scope', '$http', '$sce', function ($scope, $http, $sce) {
    $http({
        //HTTP Call
    }).success(function (response) {
        $scope.parent_page = $sce.trustAsHtml(response);
    });

    $http({
        //HTTP Call
    }).then(function (response) {
        $scope.formData.parent_page_id = response.data.parent_page_id;
        $('#parentPage option[value='+$scope.formData.parent_page_id+']').attr('selected','selected');
    });

}]);
```

and this is my HTML.

```
<select name="parent_pages" id="parentPage" ng-bind-html="parent_page" ng-model="formData.parent_page_id">
</select>
```

as i am rendering options from ajax call into ng-bind-html and when in second ajax call after getting value for selected option i am selecting option and it is selected also like

```
<option value="2" selected="selected">About Us</option>
```

but does not show as default selected value although it has selected attribute.
and jquery version is jQuery v1.11.2

Comment: Simply selected is enough. No need assignment

Comment: check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/314636/how-do-you-select-a-particular-option-in-a-select-element-in-jquery

Comment: why not you check this out: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select

Comment: Why you implement jquery in angular? it's very poor idea.

Comment: what is type of value of response.data.parent_page_id?

Comment: @RameshRajendran it is already build project i know its poor idea but i just make some changes in this  project 70% is written like this

Comment: @AnkitVadi it is string and it is also append selected="selected"  for selected option but does not show as default option as selected

Answer (score 0):

Try 'prop' function and be sure 
 `$scope.formData.parent_page_id`  return value.

```
  $('#parentPage option[value='+$scope.formData.parent_page_id+']').prop('selected', true);
```

[Sample fiddle using jQuery v1.11.2](https://jsfiddle.net/shree/zfhkzyL2/)

Comment: yes i am assure it returned value but solution you give does not work it only work for $('#parentPage option[value='+$scope.formData.parent_page_id+']').attr('selected','selected'); and i can see selected option in DOM as well

Comment: and it is jQuery v1.11.2