# Chrome console script to select options in a drop down menu

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have a page with a lot of food items there are a few options for me to select for each food item. I want to sequentially select Order for everything on the menu. Is there a script to make this happen? Thanks!

```
<select class="form-control" onchange="setFlag(999$(this).val(),$('option:selected', this).html());">                                                                               </select>
    <option value="Order"> Make this order </option>
    <option value="Veto"> Veto this order </option>
```

Answer (score 2):

**HTML**

```
<select id="sel">
<option value="Order"> Make this order </option>
<option value="Veto"> Veto this order </option>
  </select>
```

**JS**

```
document.querySelector("#sel").value = "Veto" // selects 2nd option from dropdown
```

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/6068322/1115876

something like

```
$('[value="Order"]').prop('selected', true)
```

should work