# Selecting similar options from dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a dropdown  with several  in it. I am writing some jQuery to default to the  of a logged in user. The problem is when some of my  text is too similar.

```
//this variable gets the branch name of the logged in user
var branchName = $(".logged-in-branch-name").text();
//this makes the dropdown select the correct branch for the logged in user
$("#branchcode option:contains('" + branchName + "')").prop('selected', true);
```

This is all well and good. Except when text is to similar. Example:

"College 1"
"College 1 - Online"

When the variable branchName is "College 1", the dropdown always defaults to "College 1 - Online".

When the variable is "College 1 - Online", it correctly goes to the "College 1 - Online" dropdown.

Any thoughts on how I can filter these correctly?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you want to match exactly?

Comment: You might want to select option by value. not contains. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/314636/how-do-you-select-a-particular-option-in-a-select-element-in-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than have contains, check the absolute text value.

```
$("#branchcode").find('option').each(function(){
    if ($(this).text() === branchName)
    {
        $(this).prop('selected', true);
    }
});
```

or even

```
$("#branchcode").find('option').each(function(){
      $(this).prop('selected', $(this).text() === branchName);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Swap this line:

```
$("#branchcode option:contains('" + branchName + "')").prop('selected', true);
```

For this code:

```
$("#branchcode option')
    .filter(function () {
        return $(this).text() === branchName;
    })
    .prop('selected', true);
```

The problem with your code is that `:contains` when used in your case with "College 1" is matching both "College 1" **and** "College 1 - Online", and I will assume (since you didn't provided the html) that the select is not multiple so the last matching option ends selected.

---

Depending your html you might need to handle whitespace before or after the text of the option element, just throw a $.trim in there:

```
return $.trim($(this).text()) === branchName;
```