# Selecting Chosen options through javascript functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-chosen

I've been trying to implement a solution proposed in [How do you select a particular option in a SELECT element in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/314636/how-do-you-select-a-particular-option-in-a-select-element-in-jquery/15159735#15159735) to no avail.  Either the addition of Chosen to the mix makes the solution invalid, or I've made some coding error that is beyond my compiler and me to find.

My html:

```
<select name="superType" class="chosen-select chosen-select-creation-allowed" id="superType" style="width: 300px; display: none;" onchange="loadInheritance()" multiple="">
  <option style="padding-left:20px;" value=""></option><option style="padding-left:0px" value="28">concept</option>
  <option style="padding-left:20px" value="30">human</option>
</select>
```

When I place the following after this, I expect one of them will add to the value="30" option above a 'selected' attribute:

```
      //$('#superType option[value="30"]').prop('selected', true);
        $('#superType option[value="30"]').attr('selected', 'selected');
        $('.chosen-select').trigger("chosen:updated");
```

Instead, nothing happens as according to the DOM model inspector and visual presentation.

What I want is to have this selection happen inside a function, but when I try to build the reference to the option above I get the error:

```
Syntax error, unrecognized expression: '#superType option[value="30"]'
```

Here is the javascript generating that (procs on 'cid'):

```
            //now go back through and select the ones this CommonNoun already had from before
            $.ajax({
                url: '/BackToTech/server?function=getExistingSuperTypes',
                type: 'POST',
                success: function (response){
    //              var target = $("#superType");           
                    var target = "#superType";          
                    selectOptions(response, target, 0);
                    $('.chosen-select').trigger("chosen:updated");
                }
            });
```

...

```
function selectOptions(obj, target) {
    var concepts = obj; 
    $.each(concepts, function(concept, value) {  
        alert(concept, value);
        if (concept == "cid") {
            optionValue = obj[concept].oid;
            $("'" + target + " option[value=\"" + optionValue + "\"]'").attr('selected', 'selected');
        } else { 
            selectOptions(value, target);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: why do you have single quotes around your css selector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the single quotes around the css selector.

```
$(`${target} option[value="${optionValue}"]`).attr('selected', 'selected');
```