# issue with set autoselect value in multiple select box with jquery

Tags: html, jquery, css, jquery-select2

I am using skote theme and I want to set auto select value in multiple select select box when edit data I have get this multiple select box from this [this](https://themesbrand.com/skote/layouts/vertical/form-advanced.html) for that I am trying below code

```
    <select class="select2 form-control select2-multiple" name="assign_to[]" multiple="multiple"                                     data-placeholder="Choose ...">
    <option value="1" data-select2-id="1">Admin</option>
    <option value="2" data-select2-id="2">Admin2</option>
    <option value="3" data-select2-id="3">Admin3</option>
</select>


    $(document).on('click','.edittodotask',function(e){

    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).attr('id').replace('edittodotask_', '');
    var url = "{{route('task_to_do.edit', ':id')}}";            
    url = url.replace(":id", id);

    
    $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        url: url,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function(response) {
            //response = assign_to: "1, 2"                
            var assign_to = response.assign_to.split(',');                
            $("#edit_assign_to").val(assign_to);            
        },
        error: function(data) {
            console.log(data);


        }
    })
    
});
```

when I click on edit button I have get data with ajax and want to set auto select options for that I have make this code

but it is not set selected value.

can anybody help me with this

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you select a particular option in a SELECT element in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/314636/how-do-you-select-a-particular-option-in-a-select-element-in-jquery)

Comment: @alotropico I want to select multiple items not a single item

Comment: Show us the full HTML code, no foreach's

Comment: It's exactly the same, once for each option you want selected $('#edit_assign_to option:eq(1), #edit_assign_to option:eq(2)').prop('selected', true);

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy I have put full script of my code please check my edited question

Comment: I specifically said the HTML code without foreach's ;) I need to see the values

Comment: @alotropico if I put this code it is selecting value but it is not showing options as per that theme it is not making default li like `<li class="select2-selection__choice" title="admin" data-select2-id="6"><span class="select2-selection__choice__remove" role="presentation">×</span>admin</li>`

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy please check it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using select2, you need to trigger the changes manually.

```
$("#edit_assign_to").val(response.assign_to.split(',')).trigger('change.select2');
```

If your data returns `1, 2` with a comma, you need to split by `,`  with a space after the comma.