# Is it possible to submit a form even though the user is not interacting with the input box?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a simple form and would like to submit the form but for some reason the form fails and simply refreshes the page. I am using ajax.

```
<ul>
<li> 1 </li>
<li> 2 </li>
</ul>
```

When the user clicks on the li element - the number is then displayed in the inbox using:

```
$(".input1").val(e.target.innerhtml); 
$(".input1").removeAttr("readonly");
```

(A) But when I click submit the form does not submit.

(B) However, if I manually click on the input box and insert the number 2. The form submits just fine.

I created a web app and i do not want the keyboard to appear. Instead I use css to display a scrolling list of numbers for the user to click/select from.

Comment: It would be more helpful if you could provide the related html code so we can reproduce this

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO.  Please do take the time to read the [tour] and [ask].   In this case, your question would also benefit from a snippet that demonstrates the issue - include only the minimum code needed to demonstrate/reproduce the issue.  See [mcve].

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is good old [`<select>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select) with [`<options>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option) tags.
As you can read on the MDN (linked in both tags above), `<select>` can be a child / descendant of the `<form>` element. Reading chosen values from this is also fairly easy - everything is described in the 1st link, along with HTML, CSS & JS snippets.

Or try looking for something that covers `<select>` with jQuery - e.g. [How do you select a particular option in a SELECT element in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/314636/how-do-you-select-a-particular-option-in-a-select-element-in-jquery)

Comment: Thanks Gawron - That worked like a charm and to everyone else - my bad for not providing enough detail in the snippet.