# How do I check if no option is selected in a selectbox using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html-select

I am trying to see if an option was selected in a selectbox and if not, I want it to alert a string. I was referring to this link([Check if option is selected with jQuery, if not select a default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149573/check-if-option-is-selected-with-jquery-if-not-select-a-default)), but its not working.

Here's my code:

```
<select id="language" name="language">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>

if(!$("#language option:selected").length) {
  alert('no option is selected');
}
```

I pretty much copied the linked answer, but it's still not working. What am I missing?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Another way to go is:

```
  if($("#language").attr("selectedIndex") == 0) {
    alert("You haven't selected anything!");
   }
```

Working example at: http://jsbin.com/eluki3/edit

Comment: This was my preferred solution but I had to use .prop('selectedIndex') instead of .attr("selectedIndex") to get it to work.

Answer (score 8):

perhaps because the first one is selected by default.

try using

```
if($('#language :selected').text() == ''){
   alert('no option is selected');
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
if ( $("#language option:selected").val() === "" )
{
    alert("No items selected");
}
```

or simply

```
if ( $("#language").val() === "" )
{
    alert("No items selected");
}
```

Comment: Need to be careful if the HTML is `<option>` rather than `<option value="">`, otherwise `val()` will return the text contents of the option.  Doesn't apply to this example as both are blank but as been the source of more than a few bugs!

Answer (score 1):

I solved the same issue using:

```
if ($('#mySelector option:selected').get().length>0) {
    //code
} else ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you put the jQuery code inside a

`$(function() { });`

?

It needs to be evaluated after the DOM is ready.