# Check if an select option exists based on text in jQuery 1.7

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

So I have the following piece of HTML:

```
<select id="sel">
<option value="0">Option1</option>
<option value="1">Option2</option>
<option value="2">Option3</option>
<option value="3">Option4</option>
</select>
```

How do I check to see if #sel has an option based on the text value? ("Option1")

Comment: Found this past question that should provide assistance to your problem [Possible Solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2385963/how-do-i-check-if-no-option-is-selected-in-a-selectbox-using-jquery)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try the following:

```
var opt = 'Option1';
if ($('#sel option:contains('+ opt +')').length) {
   alert('This option exists')
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FPDCu/)

edit: The above snippet uses the jQuery `contains` selector which filters elements that their textContent *contains* the specified value. For an exact match you can use the code snippet suggested in christian-mann's answer.

> How to do this with Javascript (not jquery) – Jerry

```
var optionExists = [].some.call(document.getElementById('sel').options, function(option) {
   return option.textContent === 'value';
});
```

Comment: It will fail if the select only has `Option112`

Comment: `contains` doesn't equate to 'is an exact match', so that will return a positive match for `<option value="0">HocusPocusOption1</option>`.  http://jsfiddle.net/FPDCu/212

Comment: @user1063287 That's true, for exact match Christian's suggested snippet can be used.

Comment: How to do this with Javascript (not jquery)

Answer (score 9):

The jQuery filter function accepts a function as its argument:

```
$('#sel option').filter(function() { 
    return $(this).text() === "Option1"; 
});
```

Comment: How to make it dynamic?

Answer (score 1):

```
var length = $('#sel option').filter(function() { 
    return $(this).text() === "Option1"; 
}).length;

if(length == 0)
    console.log('This option text doesn't exist.');
else
    console.log('This option text exists ' + length + ' times.');
```

If length is 0, it doesn't exist. I typically don't like using contains, because it's not an exact match.

Answer (score 0):

```
var hasOption1=$("option:contains('Option1')", "#sel").length==1; //true or false
```

Comment: It will fail if the select only has `Option112`

Comment: I did, that's why I didn't downvote your answer. You should probably underline that there's no strict comparison selector and `filter(fn)` should be used instead.