# shorter way to check if an option exists

Tags: javascript, jquery

I hope there is a shorter way to check if an option inside `sela` exists.

Any suggestion?

```js
var str = 'white moon';
var x = 0;
$('#sela > option').each(function(){
if($(this).text() == str){x = 1;}
});

if(x == 1){console.log(x);}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id='sela'>
<option>blue sky</option>
<option>gold sun</option>
<option>white moon</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if an select option exists based on text in jQuery 1.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11639023/check-if-an-select-option-exists-based-on-text-in-jquery-1-7)

Comment: @Manoz, the question is duplicated, but the answer is much better here (`Jitendra's` answer);

Comment: I still don't see any difference b/w both the accepted answers. This is clearly a duplicate.

Comment: @qadenza the two answers are identical (first answer on duplicate and Jitendra's here) - or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will check given option exist on dropdown.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log($("#sela option:contains(white moon)").length);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id='sela'>
  <option>blue sky</option>
  <option>gold sun</option>
  <option>white moon</option>
</select>
```

Comment: It won't work if you want to check if an option exists (as requested in the question) if the look-for is also part of another option eg `<option>blue moon</option>` as `$("select option:contains(blue)")` will find `blue moon` and not `blue`.  It's ok if you know that's what you're looking for, but not to *explicitly* **"check if an option exists"**.

Comment: For an exact match, use the existing answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11639134/2181514

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($('#sela option').length > 0) {
  console.log('exist');
}

//if specific option exist
if($("#sela option[value='yourValue']").length > 0) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not giving value attribute to your option ? then you can easily selected the one you want

```js
var str = 'white moon';
console.log($('#sela>option[value="'+str+'"]'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id='sela'>
<option value="blue sky">blue sky</option>
<option value="gold sun">gold sun</option>
<option value="white moon">white moon</option>
</select>
```