# Jquery detect bootstrap multiple option dropdown being unselected

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a dynamic bootstrap multiple drop down selector.

I would like to run some code when a user un-selects a option.

```
<select id="selectOptions" multiple>
  <option>Test1</option>
  <option>Test2</option>
  <option>Test3</option>
  <option>Test4</option>
  <option>Test5</option>
 <option>Test6</option>
</select>
```

I am thinking to do this by jquery however I have an option which already runs on selecting an option, how would I do this when a user clicks to un-select the option.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is to add a `change` listener to the `select` element and keep an array of all the items that were selected last time this listener was triggered. This way you can compare the array of items that are currently selected to the array of previously selected items to determine which ones were unselected.

Here is an example:

```js
var prevSelected = [];
$("#selectOptions").change(function(){
  var selected = $(this).val() || [];
  var unselected = prevSelected.filter(function(v){
    return selected.indexOf(v) === -1;
  });
  if(unselected.length){
    console.log("value(s) " + unselected + " were/was unselected");
  }
  prevSelected = selected;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="selectOptions" multiple>
  <option>Test1</option>
  <option>Test2</option>
  <option>Test3</option>
  <option>Test4</option>
  <option>Test5</option>
 <option>Test6</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Amazing, I needed to change the jquery to:
$(document).on('change', '#selectOption', function() {
}
However all works now. Thanks!

Comment: @JakeS I'm glad I could help. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2385963/how-do-i-check-if-no-option-is-selected-in-a-selectbox-using-jquery) post you can check for selected values like so

```
var select = document.getElementById("selectOptions");
$('#selectOptions').change(function(){
    for (index in select){
        if ( $("#selectOptions").val() === "" )
            {
                //some code
            }
    }
});
```

Comment: I need to know when a value has become un-selected and which one. I don't think this will help.

Comment: @JakeS I made an edit that might be a bit closer to what you're asking for.