# change selects value onchange of another select

Tags: jquery

i start learning jquery few days ago, and i like it very much. but now i have a problem, that can't solve alone.

i have two selects

```
<select id="select1">
  <option value="1">1day</option>
  <option value="2">2day</option>
  <option value="3">3day</option>
</select>

<select id="select2">
  <option value="1">1day</option>
  <option value="2">2day</option>
  <option value="3">3day</option>
</select>
```

i need to set `#select2` the same value with `#select1`, when `#select1` changes

i've red some questions about select tag [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149573/check-if-option-is-selected-with-jquery-if-not-select-a-default), but i need to set "selected" attribute to that option, which have the same value. how can i do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To set the value use [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) like this:

```
$(function() { //run on document.ready
  $("#select1").change(function() { //this occurs when select 1 changes
    $("#select2").val($(this).val());
  });
});
```

[You can see a working demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/QEUwg/)

This would set `<select id="select2">` to the same value as the other one has.  [`.val(vale)`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) selects the `<option>` that has the corresponding value in the `<select>`, also de-selecting the previous selection.  You use [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) without parameters to *get* the currently selected `<option>`'s value.

Comment: hmm, that's probably what he is looking for but you need to wrap your code in ready handler as well as onchange event because he seems to be a noob.

Comment: Nice!, one suggestion infact we can avoid $ on the first dropdown again and can be done with  $("#select2").val(this.value);

Comment: @Raghav - You're thinking of input elements, you can't use .value on a select :)

Comment: This is perfect, man I love stackoverflow...exactly what I needed!