# jquery: change the value of `select1` onchange of `select2` IF $('#select2').val() < $('#select1').val()

Tags: jquery

i've asked the first question about selects [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934974/change-selects-value-onchange-of-another-select), i thought, that when i resieve an answer, i would solve and the second part of my problem, but there was a short way to solve first problem, so i have to ask a question again, about second part:

i have two selects

```
<select id="select1">
      <option value="1">1day</option>
      <option value="2">2day</option>
      <option value="3">3day</option>
    </select>

    <select id="select2">
      <option value="1">1day</option>
      <option value="2">2day</option>
      <option value="3">3day</option>
    </select>
```

and i need to change the value of `select1` onchange of `select2`,

```
if $('#select2').val() < $('#select1').val();
```

i try to write the following function

```
 $("#select2").bind('change',function() {
            if($('#select2').val() < $('#select1').val())
            {
              $("#select1").val($(this).val());
            }
        });
```

but it doesn't eork, becouse on the moment of change, when i call the function, it doesn't change it's value yet.
so, what can i do?

Thakns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try change

```
$("#select1").val($(this).val());
```

to

```
$("#select1 :selected").val($(this).val());
```

( I assume you want to change the value of the currently selected element in select1 based on what you selected in select2 )

Answer (score 0):

it works for me. Note that you are binding to the select2 change event not the select1 change event. So when you change select 2, select 1 should change if it has a higher value.