# Drupal views reset exposed filters values on change

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-views, drupal-taxonomy, drupal-exposed-filter

in my view I have 3 exposed filters based on different vocabularies. My need is to use only one filter at a time, when a value is selected in one filter the two others have to be automatically reset (to "-any-"), I googled and I only found one similar question but the answer (expose reset button) doesn't really fit my need. I suspect there must be one simple solution to this common (I guess) requirement.
I'm using BEF but no help from this side I fear.
Thank you for helping !
EDIT : I put my three filters in a group using AND operator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a common requirement but anyway.

If you really need that functionality you can do this using **js (or jquery)** so when changes a select option (assuming you are using select element) to reset the other 2 selects to the -Any- option.

Check this question [change selects value onchange of another select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934974/change-selects-value-onchange-of-another-select) based to the change() jquery function.