# Display Text Using Jquery on HTML Select Tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick

I am new in programming. I have a code in which i use Jquery on HTML select tag. I have two Select Tag

```
<div style="margin-top:10px; width:280px; float:left">
<select name="s_name" id="s_name">

  <option value="shahzad">Muhammad Shahzad Saleem</option>
  <option value="hanif">Muhammad Jhangeer Hanif</option>
  <option value="rana">Rana Muhammad Nadeem</option>
  </select>

   <br> 

 <select name="s_designation">
   <option value="coo">Chief Operating Officer</option>
   <option value="uh">Unit Head</option>
 </select>
 </div>
```

On first Select tag i use Jquery

```
<script>
    $(function() {
          $('#s_name').on('change',function(){
        if( $(this).val()=="rana"){
        $("#rana").show()
        }
        else{
        $("#rana").hide()
        }
        if( $(this).val()=="hanif"){
            $("#hanif").show()
        }
        else{
        $("#hanif").hide()
        }
    });});
        </script>
```

This Jquery is working fine for the following code

```
<div id="rana" style="display:none; margin-left:350px; width:auto; float:left">

        <input type="text" name="uh1" value="Muhammad Jhangeer Hanif"/>
        </br>
        <input type="text" name="uh1_designation" value="Unit Head"/>
        </div>
<div id="hanif" style="display:none; margin-left:350px; width:auto; float:left">
            <input type="text" name="uh2" value="Rana Muhammad Nadeem"/> <br/>
            <input type="text" name="uh2_designation" value="Unit Head"/> 
  </div>
```

Now i want to use jquery on my second select tag. I want that when user change the value in select tag `s_name` then it will make change automatically in second select tag `s_designation` For example by defalut my select tag show `s_name` is `shahzad saleem` and against its designation `s_designation` is cheif operating offecier. But i want when user click on `s_name` `Hanif` or `rana` then against its designation `s_designation` will automatically change `Unit Head`.

How i can do it? please tell me, Which will work with my existing jquery as well

Comment: You can do something like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/2934987/4052834

Comment: @JoseLuis i already use `s_name` in a function. Can i use it another function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this:

```js
$(function () {
    var hanif = $("#hanif");
    var rana = $("#rana");
    var value = null;
    var sName = $('#s_name');
    var sDesignation = $('select[name="s_designation"]');
    sName.on('change', function () {
        value = $(this).val();
        hanif.toggle(value === 'hanif');
        rana.toggle(value === 'rana');
        sDesignation.val(value === 'hanif' || value === 'rana' ? 'uh' : 'coo');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="margin-top:10px; width:280px; float:left">
    <select name="s_name" id="s_name">
        <option value="shahzad">Muhammad Shahzad Saleem</option>
        <option value="hanif">Muhammad Jhangeer Hanif</option>
        <option value="rana">Rana Muhammad Nadeem</option>
    </select>
    <br />
    <select name="s_designation">
        <option value="coo">Chief Operating Officer</option>
        <option value="uh">Unit Head</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div id="rana" style="display:none; margin-left:350px; width:auto; float:left">
    <input type="text" name="uh1" value="Muhammad Jhangeer Hanif" />
    <br />
    <input type="text" name="uh1_designation" value="Unit Head" />
</div>
<div id="hanif" style="display:none; margin-left:350px; width:auto; float:left">
    <input type="text" name="uh2" value="Rana Muhammad Nadeem" />
    <br />
    <input type="text" name="uh2_designation" value="Unit Head" />
</div>
```

Hope this helps. Is this the kind of result you were expecting?

Comment: i did it with this `<script>
    $(function() {
          $('#s_name').on('change',function(){
     
      if( $(this).val()=="shahzad"){
   $('#s_designation').val('coo')
        
        }
      
        if( $(this).val()=="rana"){
   $('#s_designation').val('uh')
        $("#rana").show()
        }
        else{
        $("#rana").hide()
        }
  if( $(this).val()=="hanif"){
   $('#s_designation').val('uh')
   $("#hanif").show()
        }
        else{
        $("#hanif").hide()
        }
    });});
        </script>`

Comment: `<select name="s_name" id="s_name">
 
  <option value="shahzad">Muhammad Shahzad Saleem</option>
  <option value="hanif">Muhammad Jhangeer Hanif</option>
  <option value="rana">Rana Muhammad Nadeem</option>
  </select>

   <br> 
 <select name="s_designation" id="s_designation">
   <option value="coo">Chief Operating Officer</option>
   <option value="uh">Unit Head</option>
 </select>
 </div>
`

Comment: Glad I could help. Curious though, why do you have the `#s_designation` select element when you don't seem to be using it?

Comment: `<div id="rana" style="display:none; margin-left:350px; width:auto; float:left">

        <input type="text" name="uh1" value="Muhammad Jhangeer Hanif"/>
        </br>
        <input type="text" name="uh1_designation" value="Unit Head"/>
        </div>
<div id="hanif" style="display:none; margin-left:350px; width:auto; float:left">
            <input type="text" name="uh2" value="Rana Muhammad Nadeem"/> <br/>
            <input type="text" name="uh2_designation" value="Unit Head"/> `

Answer (score 1):

You have to check the value of the first `Select` element and based on it's value you can change second `select` element as follows,

**EDIT**

```
$(function() {
    $('#s_name').on('change',function(){
    if( $(this).val()=="rana"){
        $('#s_designation').val('coo');
    } else {
        $('#s_designation').val('uh');
    }
});
```

Also put an id to your second `select` as `s_designation`.

Answer (score 0):

@Sunny yes, you can use $('#s_name') in another function.