# Problem with jQuery each function iterating over selects

Tags: jquery, select, each

I have 3 selects with a couple of options. When an option is changed I want to check all of the other selects, whether they are also selected or not (selected="selected"). All of the selects are in the same form.

So far I have the following javascript to do that

```
$("#form").change(function(event){  
 $(this).find("select").each(function(){
    alert( $(this+"option:selected").length );
 });
});
```

Basically following this approach: [Check if option is selected with jQuery, if not select a default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149573/check-if-option-is-selected-with-jquery-if-not-select-a-default)

The alert doenst seem to give me 1 or 0 based on the individual $(this) select element, but strangely counts up to 2 (alerts 3 times 2 after the last select is selected. After the first select it alerts 3 times 0, after the second 3 times 1, and 3 times 2 on the last). I want it to alert for example 0 0 0, then 1 0 0 then 1 0 1 and finally 1 1 1.

Any idea how this comes and how to accomplish the wanted? thx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your inner selector is incorrect. It should be:

```
$(this).find("option:selected").length
```

You can't prepend a dom element to a selector (since they are not strings). You'll end up with a selector that looks something like "Object objectoption:selected" since it will implicitly call the `.toString()` method as it is being used with the dual purpose `+` operator.

jQuery selectors need to be well-formed [CSS3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/) selectors.

Answer (score 1):

`this+"option:selected"` is not a valid selector.  Try:

```
$(this).find("option:selected").length
```