# check if option in a select dropdown is available

Tags: javascript, jquery

this might be related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149573/check-if-option-is-selected-with-jquery-if-not-select-a-default)

I have a dropdown menu that outputs a option list. In some cases the backend script outputs no options for the select tag.

I want to run a js/jquery that checks for the existence of option tags. If option tag available do nothing If no option tag available run function X.

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

```
if ( $("#select_id option").length == 0 ) {
    function()
}
```

Comment: I tried this:function hideThebutton() {
   $("add-to-cart").hide(); 
  };
  if ($("#size-attribute option").length == 0 ) {
     hideThebutton();   
     }; but it does not work any idea why, I want to run this on page load obviously

Answer (score 1):

You can use `length` to count the number of elements matched by a selector. In this case, write a selector that matches any of the `<option>` tags inside your select:

```
if ($('select.my_select option').length > 0) {
  // There are options inside <select class="my_select">
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("select").each(function(){
    if(this.childNodes.length > 0)
        process();
});
```