# Selecting values from a multiple select picklist with Javascript

Tags: php, javascript

How would I set values of a picklist with Javascript? Like for example, a page loads, and I want several values of a picklist to be selected (I will generate these with PHP from the database and echo the actual Javascript). I don't need the actual page load part, just how to select a value out of a picklist (with multiple select)

Comment: Why don't you mark them as selected right within PHP, when you create the page?

Comment: Check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/149573/check-if-option-is-selected-with-jquery-if-not-select-a-default

Comment: @JakeSmith You add a `selected` attribute to every `<option>` that should be selected. No JavaScript needed at all.

Answer (score 4):

A [select](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp) contains an `options` collection.  Each element therein has a `selected` property.  To select certain items in your `select`, just use a simple loop and set `selected` to true for the desired options:

```
<select id="multiPickList" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="1">A</option>
    <option value="2">B</option>
    <option value="3">C</option>
    <option value="4">D</option>
    <option value="5">E</option>
</select>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var pl = document.getElementById("multiPickList");
    for (i = 0; i < pl.options.length; i++) {
       if (i % 2 == 0) {
          pl.options[i].selected = true;
       }
    }
</script>
```