# jquery make selection

Tags: jquery

I have a drop down.
One of the selections is Please Enter.

How do I force it to go to Please Enter

The id of the selectlist is called makeSelection

```
     $('select.makeSelection').val("Please Enter").attr('selected', 'selected');
```

Comment: `id`s use a `#`. Try this first: `$('select#makeSelection')`

Comment: @wanovak There's no need to filter by tag name first with an ID.

Comment: @JamesMcLaughlin I just wanted to make the point that OP need only change one character to have working code. But you *are* right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#makeselection option[value='Press Enter']").prop('selected', 'selected');
```

For jQuery 1.6 you can use

```
$("#makeselection option[value='Press Enter']").attr('selected', 'selected');
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mprabhat/VvJrx/)

Edit : Similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149573/check-if-option-is-selected-with-jquery-if-not-select-a-default)

You may even be interested in [why Prop and Attr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr)

Answer (score 0):

If makeSelection is the Id, there will be only one so

```
   $('#makeSelection').val("Please Enter").attr('selected', 'selected');
```

is enough.

Answer (score 0):

Change your selector to:

`$('#makeSelection').val("Please Enter").attr('selected', 'selected');`

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/senoramor/bNG4S/)