# html select default

Tags: html

In the html  tag, is there something like

```
<select default="someValue" ... >
```

or

to specify the value being selected when the page is loaded? I don't have access to the single options, so

```
<option value="" selected> ...
```

does not work for me.

Comment: Whatdo you mean by _I don't have access to single options_? How do you know that the value you wan't to be default _is_ in the options if you don't have access to them?

Answer (score 1):

```
<option value="something" selected="selected">
```

Is the only *html* way. But you can do this with [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), e.g. give your select an ID `<select id="mySelect">`

and

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#mySelect option[value='someValue']").attr('selected', 'selected');
});
```

If you don't want to use jQuery, there also is a [plain javascript solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/149620/180174)

Answer (score 0):

```
 <select id="Select1" >
           <option value="x" selected="selected">x</option>
           <option value="y">Y</option>
  </select>
```