# Check if options is selected

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Check if option is selected with jQuery, if not select a default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149573/check-if-option-is-selected-with-jquery-if-not-select-a-default)

I have html like this:

```
<div id="somedivid">

<select class="someclass">
<!-- options -->
</select>

<select class="someclass">
<!-- options -->
</select>

</div>
```

How to check if options is selected in both select boxes?

EDIT: i cant change html, so it means i cant add ids to select elements.

Comment: what i did was wrote your questions topic + 'jquery' to google, and [look what i found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/149573/check-if-option-is-selected-with-jquery-if-not-select-a-default)

Comment: @Tom well, you found solution when there is only one select element. I know how to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A select always has a selection.

But supposing you put an empty choice like this :

```
​<select id=select1>
    <option></option>
    <option>A</option>
    <option>B</option>
</select>​
```

You can test this :

```
if ($('#select1').val() && $('#select2').val()) {
   // both have selection
```

EDIT : if you don't have ids or names, you may use this :

```
var allSelected = true:
$('#somedivid select').each(function() {
    if (!$(this).val()) {
       allSelected = false;
       break;
    }
});
```

Comment: Yeah, i know to do that, but my select elements does not have ids, only classes that are same for both elements. And i cant change html.

Comment: I edited for a solution if you don't have ID or name. But you must define what does mean that something is selected (for example empty choice).

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( function() { 
        $( '#somedivid > select' ).bind( 'change', function(){
            if( $( '#sel1').attr( 'value' ) != 'default' && $( '#sel1' ).attr( 'value' ) != 'default' ){
                //do something here.
            }
        });
    } );
</script>
<div id="somedivid">

    <select id="sel1">
        <option value="default" selected="selected"></option>
        <!-- options -->
    </select>

    <select id="sel2">
        <option value="default" selected="selected"></option>
        <!-- options -->
    </select>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering both selectbox has some default option value ="none"

```
var isBothSelected=0;
if($('#selectbox1 option:selected').val() =='none'){
    alert('Plase select the select1');
    isBothSelected=isBothSelected+1;
    //return false;
}
if($('#selectbox2 option:selected').val() =='none'){
    alert('Plase select the select2');
   isBothSelected=isBothSelected+1;
    // return false;
}
if(isBothSelected ==2){
  alert('Both are not selected')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
      var val=  $("#selectid option:selected").value();
           if(val==="")
               {
          alert("your code on not selected condition");
           }
```