# radio button checked required

Tags: javascript, asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can i check if a radio button is selected in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1423777/how-can-i-check-if-a-radio-button-is-selected-in-javascript)

I am trying to implement client side validation on radio buttons. For example, pay status is either paid or unpaid. If they do not select any, I want it to say "Select your pay status." If either is checked, it will already display in a label through server side validation.

```
<script language="javascript">
$document.ready function() {
valButton = function(btn) {
for (var i=btn.length-1; i > -1; i--) {
    if (btn[i].checked) return btn[i].value;
  }
  return null;
}

if (null === valButton (document.getElementsByName (document.getElementById('rdoPaid').name)) {
  message('Select a pay status.');
}
});
</script>


Pay Status
<input ID="rdoPaid" Text="Paid" />
<br />
<input ID="rdoUnpaid" Text="Unpaid" />
```

Instead of input, I am really using asp:RadioButton.

This is what I was trying. Can anyone help me getting this to work properly?

Comment: It looks like this question covers what you're after: [How can i check if a radio button is selected in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1423777/how-can-i-check-if-a-radio-button-is-selected-in-javascript) Check out the comments in Mark Biek's answer as they contain more info relevant to your question.

Comment: Also, if you can use jQuery, I just answered a similar question earlier today: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12629504/issues-with-javascript-validation-of-radio-buttons-on-php-form/12631814#12631814

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
if(!document.getElementById('rdoPaid').checked){
    message('Select a pay status.');
}
```