# jQuery - Check If any select option is selected

Tags: jquery

Basically I have a select option which pulls all the 'Tour Names' from a database as $touroptions. $touroptions can contain anything from 1-20 values (select options).

What I need to do is have a jQuery function to do as follows so:-

```
If (any option) #sel-destination-tour is selected {
//DO SOMETHING
}
ELSE {
//DO SOMETHING ELSE
}
```

I'm just not sure how I could do this.

**HTML**

```
<select name="sel-destination-tour" id="sel-destination-tour" class="input-select-tour">

    <option value="0"></option>

    <?php echo $touroptions ?>

</select>
```

Comment: I'm guessing by the HTML you supply that 0 is the default option and you want that counted as nothing selected?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/149820/4695280

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can check whether a option by testing the value attribute of the select

```
if($('#sel-destination-tour').val()){
    // do something
} else {
    // do something else
}
```

Comment: what if the option's value is 0?

Comment: It's better to check against `null`, since `0` might be a valid option value, but it would evaluate to `false` in your case. I.e. `$('#sel-destination-tour').val() != null`.

Answer (score 4):

try this

```
$('#sel-destination-tour').val() == ""){
    //nothing selected;
}else{
    //something selected;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

track the change event of select and do your stuffs accordingly

```
$(function(){

 $("#sel-destination-tour").change(function(){

 if($(this).val() !="0")
  {
    // logic goes here
  }
  else
  {
   // no option is selected
  }
});

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have the first item as shown in your example, this will do it...

```
if ($("#sel-destination-tour").val() != "0") {
    // nothing selected
} else {
    // something selected
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the `val()` (assuming 0 is no value):

```
if ($('#sel-destination-tour').val() != 0) {
   // has a value selected
} 
else {
   // does not have a value selected
}
```

Example - http://jsfiddle.net/infernalbadger/RrtT7/

Comment: Just a comment : `.val()` method wont work in some cases, i dont know the correct situations, it happens in FF ( especially with large set of options that `change` is  triggerd programically )

Answer (score 0):

In my situation `val()` was returning `[]` and coming up as `true`. So I changed it to:

```
if($('#sel-destination-tour').val()[0]){
    // do something
} else {
    // do something else
}
```